# Is it improper to use the vba tag on application specific vba questions?

Tags: discussion, tags

On the [vba info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vba/info) it says:

> More importantly, this tag is for VBA code that can be used in
>   multiple Office applications.

I see why this is, and tend to agree with it. However, that is not how the tag is actually being used. Practically all of the application specific questions I see are tagged with both the vba and the application specific tag. I'm not complaining, because I find this useful when searching for questions to answer/help with. I'm just wondering where the community stands on this. Should the tag be redefined as something more generic, or should there be effort put into properly retagging these questions?

Update:
There is also [this discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252988/3198973) going on right now, which makes me believe editing the wiki would be the right thing to do.

Update2:
I submitted an edit to the wiki and it has been approved by reviewers.
[Revision History here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3612078/revisions).

Comment: There's an old meta answer from Joel Spolsky on this very subject [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/110909/150559)

Comment: @barrowc That's not exactly what I mean, but I would agree with the sentiment that [Excel][vba] != [Excel-vba]. I'm talking about using the [vba] tag on any vba question that is application specific. I think the wiki needs to be changed.

Comment: I like your edit; the confusion largely reflects Microsoft's internal confusion regarding whether VBA is really "one language" (with the differences in object models, there is preciously little value in attempting to write code that will run in multiple applications; and don't even start me about the differences between Mac and PC versions of the "same" Office application and associated VBA differences).

Comment: I often use both tags. I mean almost *anything* in VBA that is outside of the Application-specific object model is *not* application-specific.

Answer (score 12):

After looking at that tag wiki, I don't really understand why they want people to tag with the application-specific VBA tags instead of (or in addition to) the broader VBA one.

Perhaps it's because the object models are so different between the applications, and answerers tend to specialize in one particular application.  For instance, I've worked extensively with the Access object model, but have almost no knowledge or experience in the Excel, Word or PowerPoint object models.

Naturally, I would "follow" the [access-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access-vba) tag, but not the others.

Given the [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) Tag Wiki's description (that it only be used for questions involving multiple Office products), I would expect its use to be exceedingly rare.  In any case, VBA is merely a programming language, and doesn't have any special status as such.  It can even be embedded in other applications besides Office (e.g. Visual Pinball).

The advice in the VBA tag wiki is at odds with the generally-accepted advice for using language tags, which is to tag a question with the broad language tag, and then add a version-specific language tag if that specific tag also applies to the question.

Comment: from the excerpt history it's actually Spolsky, the guy who invented VBA who added that sentence to the wiki. Maybe he expected pure questions on the VBA as language ( like classes, inheritance etc as those would be non-application specific ). [Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19373081/how-to-use-the-implements-in-excel-vba) I personally thought should be tagged VBA and possibly additionally EXCEL-VBA

Comment: No kidding.  Maybe I ought to ask Joel what he was thinking.  Perhaps he had too much [Wasabi](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2006/09/01b.html) that day.

Comment: If it is at odds with the generally accepted advice [citation?], then I'm of the thought that the wiki needs changed, not how we use the tag.

Comment: @ckuhn203: I have no opinion about that.  As a general rule of thumb, Tag Communities do have some discretion over how tags are used.

Answer (score 6):

Not being cocky here or anything but having been in the top ten in VBA tag I can tell you about my experience with it; trust me I have read/seen hundreds if not thousands of questions tagged [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) and its other variants.

Since I got familiar with the favorite tags feature I have always had [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) and [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba) added as I am most familiar with the Excel object model. I find people tagging their Ms Office related questions mostly with the [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) and it's quite rare to see [powerpoint-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powerpoint-vba) and not [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba). Sometimes you see them combined. Sometimes you see [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) and [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel) instead of like [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba)[excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba) etc.

I mostly answer [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) and [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba) questions and it makes it easier for me when the question is tagged with both. I rather avoid pure [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel) questions as most of them actually belongs on SuperUser and I really do not want / have time to filter out all the general questions asked on Ms Office (non-programmatic ones).

In my opinion, I like the distinction because you can favorite the tags you feel the most comfortable with and avoid other tags you're not familiar with.

See, not being rude, but a beginner may not be familiar with the [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) history and may think it only applies to Excel, or Word. There are actually plenty of applications which use (or could use) VBA library - only if they are COM based.

In cases where a user wants to ask a question on CATIA and there was no CATIA tag and he wouldn't have enough reputation to introduce a tag then how would he tag his question? :) Pure VBA ftw:)

Additionally,

There is a little cheat I use once in a while to get a quick access to the questions I probably more likely enjoy reading and answering by putting a [search query](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) together. I combine [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) with other ones like [oop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oop), [class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/class), [interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interface), [properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/properties) etc to narrow down the questions to those more abstract ones which are far more interesting than "how to find the last row" hehe

Comment: So... Go ahead an use both tags then?

Comment: I like being able to follow the high level vba tag as well.

Comment: @RobertHarvey yea, that's the point. Use both - it's not like a question on Excel needs to  use all 5 tags. Mostly it will be Excel, Spreadsheet, Vba, ADODB, Pivot and very rarely all at once

Comment: @mehow Would you agree that the wiki needs updated then? I'm pretty new here and I found it confusing. Others will too.

Comment: @ckuhn203 yes in fact it does. Feel free to suggest an edit :)

Comment: Edit is in the review queue @mehow.

Comment: @ckuhn203 well done I have reviewed 20 suggested edits already today but I am sure others will approve it, let us know the outcome.

Comment: haha. No worries. My suggested edit was approved. I updated my question with a link to the revision history.

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion, it's fine to use that tag for that purpose. The main purpose of adding a tag should be, "Will there be a body of people following this tag who can likely answer my question". You may be writing VBA for Outlook, but a VBA expert who is very likely to answer doesn't follow that tag, but only the broad VBA tag. And most importantly, you *are* writing VBA.

<strike>I think the wording of that info might be a bit off, as I can see how it might suggest what you are worrying about here. I'm going to edit it.</strike>

After reading the existing info on the tag, I'm not going to make the edit, but wait for community consensus. It seems some people strongly disagree with me.