# When to use broader tags vs narrow tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

I recently tried tagging a question with [java-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-7) versus the broader [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tag because it had to do with [java-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-7) not [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) as a whole due to a feature added in Java7 having to do with the addition of week year in `SimpleDateFormat`.

A minor edit war occurred whereas the [java-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-7) tag was either removed and replaced with [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), or [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) was added in conjunction with [java-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-7).

I wasn't aware that there are sub-tags within StackOverflow. I flagged the post but my flag was declined because the moderator said the broader [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tag was permitted here. I disagree but I lost on appeal, so it goes.

What is the appropriate convention? I feel that the broader [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tag does not apply and will confuse future readers. It should left to just [java-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-7).

Comment: Why would the `java` tag confuse? Version specific tags are always clarifications; use the main language tag so that more people interested in that language can see the post.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: The thought process is that the tag is metadata about the post. Yes, it has Java code but the Java code in particular which is the crux of the problem only applies to Java7

Comment: Yes, so it is *still Java*. Ditto for `python` and `python-2.7` or `python-3.x`. Great that you add a version specific tag, but *why is it a problem that it is tagged with `java` in the first place*?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: `public static void main(...)` is Java.. intricacies of `SimpleDateFormat` could apply only to certain versions. :)

Comment: So, it is *still part of Java*. It won't ever apply to Java 8?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: It will apply to Java7 (I don't know about Java8 but see no reason why to remove it). I guess my fear is that if someone sees it without the java-7 tag, then they will try it on Java6 and then we have another question asking why it doesn't work

Comment: Also my understanding of python is that the versions are different.. it's not like Java.

Comment: I agree that the `java-7` tag applies. That is not what I am asking. I am not proposing you add `java-8` either. I am asking **why the `java` tag is so bad here**.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: To me the broader Java tag applies to Java as a whole. If the feature was in Java1, sure tag it Java. But since it does not apply to Java as a whole, I see no reason to tag it with the broader tag.

Comment: No, the java tag is not a broader tag in that sense. It covers all things to do with java. There are *many* things that are specific to a java version. Most people do not follow version-specific tags however, so you *also* tag with `java`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Ok, that's why I was asking for clarification.

Answer (score 10):

Use the generic language tag.  There are many users who favorite the generic language tag so that they can look thorough all e.g. Java questions.  They're not going to see your question if you don't use the generic tag.

If your question is *specific to a particular language version,* also add the version-specific tag.