# Tag editor extraordinaire

Tags: discussion, tags, edits

I would appreciate the moderators looking at the edit frenzy which spans 11 pages of activity and is entering its third hour [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2140173/its-been-a-pleasure?tab=activity&sort=revisions&page=20).

Comment: **Moderator Note**: Let's make this about the action and not the person behind it.  Making it about the person is just causing arguments in the comments and back and forth. Our format doesn't do that very well.

Comment: Does anyone think there's value in having a conversation about whether it's appropriate for one person to make retagging edits on 395 posts in one sitting without bringing it up with the community, quality of the edits aside? I don't know if that's something that's been debated before or if it would be worth posting a follow-up question to this.

Comment: I feel that these tag edits are damaging, they tightly couple *(to use a term we are all familiar with)* two already distinct tags. `VBA` is a language and `Excel` *(amongst others)* is a subject. They are two distinct things and the tags should be distinct as well. This is a general opinion, I have no knowledge at all of `VBA`

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Chat does, though. Just a thought.

Comment: This should have been a flag on one of the posts.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: It seems this 21k user is a bit upset now and deletes his profile ("delete me"). How does that affect the answers?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Process wise if a user has requested an account deletion is there any reason why this wouldn't have occurred? The person in question has claimed elsewhere that they were told by email that their account wouldn't be deleted. Not a big deal either way, but curious to know whether SO may actually refuse to delete an account?

Comment: @brettdj The user [can contact the Stack Exchange team](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) for account deletion. Simply writing "delete me" in your profile does not mean you want your account deleted; and even if it did, that'd be a very poor method of asking, since no one would ever see it unless they visited your profile.  Also, account deletion does not delete any of their posts, since those posts are CC-Licensed; it just disassociates the user from the post.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker thx for the very quick response.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

As someone else who has a [majority of answers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048539/enderland?tab=answers) in the VBA tag, I think this is a bad set of edits to make.

Much of VBA applies to all applications using it. Some VBA is specific.  If I am trying to do something in Outlook I might be able to use code which also works in Excel. A smaller percentage of code is specific to Outlook VBA (and frankly the majority of that can be run from other applications, too).

Removing the [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) tag off of everything hides this and makes it less clear, especially since nearly EVERYONE will select [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) as their first tag.

I don't understand the need for these edits.

Comment: I first saw [Remou](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2548/fionnuala) (now fionnuala) retag `VBA` questions as `Excel-VBA` some years back, which to me made sense, as some of these questions were specific to the Excel object model, and would not have worked in Access, Outlook etc. Certainly code that works across the MSFT product suite should be tagged `VBA`  - not sure though that having both `VBA` and `Excel-VBA` for an Excel specific question is the best path.

Comment: I'd second this - it's counter-intuitive as nobody actually uses the term [tag:excel-vba] in any other context.  The language is actually called VBA for real, and you could tag the question as Access-VBA and VBA or Excel-VBA and VBA to achieve the same level of selectivity.  Tagging the questions like this is quite unhelpful as they would be excluded from tag searches for [tag:vba].

Comment: I am the proprietor of a commercial application with a large layer written in VBA which has only the most peripheral connection with Excel. I haven't reviewed all 395 edits, but if as it seems on a quick sample there has been some attempt to remove the VBA tag I need to register the strongest possible exception. I would also seriously question the judgment of anyone who took any such task upon themselves to this extent and rapidity without consulting the community.

Comment: @brettdj Shouldn't these questions be tagged [tag:excel-object-model] or [tag:excel-objects] instead of [tag:excel-vba]? See [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300056/rename-or-otherwise-replace-foo-vba-to-foo-object-model).

Comment: @ConcernedOfTunbridgeWells _nobody uses [tag:excel-vba] in any other context_, unless it's a VBA-syntax question that came up while they were programming under Excel, and they're not savvy enough to choose only [tag:vba]. Also, see [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300056/rename-or-otherwise-replace-foo-vba-to-foo-object-model).

Comment: @ZevSpitz Your suggestion is no better and just makes more application specific tags cluttering up the place!

Answer (score 23):

The issue I have with these edits is that they take two perfectly useful tags (Excel and VBA), and combine them into one tag that makes it seem like Excel's VBA is different from other flavors of VBA.  While there are APIs; it's not a fundamentally different language. It'd be like removing [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) and [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows) and changing it to [jscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jscript).

If anyone would like to add that tag in addition to [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel) and [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba), then so be it.  That's fine.

If you believe a question tagged only [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel) is off-topic, then vote to close it.  [We've had that discussion before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261875/are-excel-formulas-on-topic), and the consensus is not to vote to close certain types of excel questions.

Comment: @pnuts we try not to focus on interpersonal issues in a public arena. when it does happen, it's usually because the accused brings it up first.

Comment: @pnuts I'm ok with a downvote if that means not airing dirty laundry in public.

Comment: Peripherally, I refer you to my proposal [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300056/rename-or-otherwise-replace-foo-vba-to-foo-object-model).

Comment: @ZevSpitz no thanks we should be burning application specific tags not encouraging more.

Answer (score 13):

I just want to also point out what the [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) tag excerpt says (with my added emphasis):

Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) is an event-driven, object-oriented programming language for writing macros, used for the entire Office suite as well as other applications. If your question is specifically about programming Excel, Access, Word or Outlook, **also use the appropriate tag: excel-vba, access-vba, word-vba or outlook-vba.**

Clearly that text doesn't tell you to mutually exclude [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) from any of the specific office tags, it tells you to include both.

Comment: You probably read only the emphasized part, @pnuts. There is a condition before it, so [tag:vba] can be used as the only tag on a question. Also [tag:excel-vba] can be used as the only tag on a question, when the question is about something specific to Excel’s VBA.

Comment: I don’t agree that it’s a corollary, @pnuts. This instruction is written in [tag:vba] tag excerpt, therefore the [tag:vba] tag is already used. Now it recommends to specify further, if the question is more specific. When you use only [tag:excel-vba], you don’t see this guideline.

Comment: @pnuts And if [excel-vba were replaced with excel-object-model or excel-objects](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300056/rename-or-otherwise-replace-foo-vba-to-foo-object-model) the whole discussion would be irrelevant.

Comment: @pnuts Any suggestion to use [\*-vba] is wrong imo.

Answer (score -29):

Ok brettdj. You *won*. I am requesting a deletion of my account.

Oh btw... what an amazing suggestion to confuse people ; keyword: **also**

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5308775

[image]

and

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4700422

**not this one** vs **in addition to this in addition to this one.**

[image]

Comment: If your response to a disagreement is to delete your account, then maybe you should just take a break from the site. You provide valuable content, and it'd be a shame for your to quit over something trivial like this.

Comment: I have been on quite a long break... havent really been participating as you havent noticed. I am just fed up with all the nerds :) please delete, forget and move on.

Comment: If you really want to delete your account, then [you'll need to follow the instructions here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account). As I said, it'd be shame for you to quit over a disagreement like this.

Comment: Actually I didn't win anything. - it really doesn't matter to me if you chose to participate here or not. A functional site matters to me.

Comment: cheers, done. gl & hf

Comment: I voted to undelete entirely because I wanted to comment that while I've never personally been in your shoes (being called out on meta like this) I think you will be doing both yourself and the community a disservice by leaving. I hope you can still be a part of this site while aquiescing to the will of the community that these *particular* edits of yours were not welcome.

Comment: I just now saw this. I've gotta say that I don't understand what happened here. I made the edit you linked to [at your recommendation](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252994/3198973) many moons ago.

Comment: @pnuts Shouldn't have [\*-vba] full stop it's just noise. Should be synonym of [tag:object-modal] and used along with the application specific tag like [tag:excel] for example. Encouraging use of these tags is just wrong and serves a small few who want to be able to filter their queues easily. It's got nothing to do with losing information as the excuse goes.