# Is this implication true: [excel] + [vba] => [excel-vba]?

Tags: discussion, tags

Going through one of review queues I've noticed that one of StackOverflow users is making a lot of edits according to the following rule:

> If question is tagged with [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel) and [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba), add [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba) tag.

Small example: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8208780

If we go to list of the question tagged with [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba), we can see that from 41,725 tagged questions, ~22k is tagged with [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel) and ~17k with [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba).

*Please notice that there are also following problems*:

- [word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word)+[vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) vs [word-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word-vba),
- [ms-access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-access)+[vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) vs [ms-access-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-access-vba),
- ...

In my opinion [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) is way too general and creates one big mess with tagging. This situation encourage also some users to make a lot of edits which aren't very useful.

Should there be something done with [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) (e.g. better encouragement to use tags like [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba))? What is the purpose of having question tagged at the same time with [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel), [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) and [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba)?

Comment: Such edits are not very useful IMO. The vba tag could do with a bigger "Use the correct tags" warning though.

Comment: It makes little sense.  But there's more going on in the [excel] tag.  There's been some serious fighting in that community, including a loud rage-quit by a hi-rep user.  The retagging appears to be a side-effect.  Unless you have a stake in normalizing things a bit in that community, it is probably best to stay a mile away from the ruckus.

Comment: I haven't seen too many of these tag edits myself but if they are localized around a single answerer, perhaps someone is trying to achieve an `excel-vba` tag badge.

Comment: @Jeeped: this is rather situation when one user is trying to achieve 2k rep with as simple edits as possible.

Comment: @Qiu - That makes sense given the rep pt total that user is currently at. TBH, I only came to this discussion because it looked like an Excel formula question i could answer.

Comment: The edit sucks.  But I don't see what's wrong with [tag:vba].  Yes, there are differences between word, excel, outlook, access, etc, but there is still a common language.  Someone can be a "vba" expert, so  I see value in the tag.

Comment: @psubsee2003: the question is more like: "What is the purpose of having post tagged with [tag:vba], [tag:excel] and [tag:excel-vba] at the same time?"

Comment: I think that the [tag:excel-vba]-type tags are the superfluous ones here.  The question is about [tag:excel] programming using [tag:vba] - the combo tag is not useful.

Comment: @Qiu I was responding specificly to your statement of "Should there be something done with vba".  My opinion is no.

Comment: [I'm getting flashbacks here.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288749/tag-editor-extraordinaire/288760#288760)

Comment: `Should there be something done with vba`, well, yes, but I don't think it's going away anytime soon ;)

Comment: @BJMyers The point of [tag:excel-vba] is to differentiate between generally automating the Excel object model, and [tag:excel-formulas] or creating Excel addins [tag:excel-addin]. However I think that the purpose would be better served if the tag was [tag:excel-object-model] instead of [tag:excel-vba] -- [see here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300056/rename-or-otherwise-replace-foo-vba-to-foo-object-model).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, the equation is true. **The edits are not very useful** in my opinion, **but they are also harmless**.

[vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) is a useful tag, because if you can program VBA in Word, chances are you can program VBA in Excel too. **Excel VBA is still VBA.**

[excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel) is also a useful tag. Sometimes, a user asks about a specific problem and wants to do it with VBA, but another user knows how to do it by only using Excel formulas.

Therefore, both tags are needed. [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba) makes it easier to filter and follow questions, but otherwise *doesn't add information* to questions already tagged with [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) + [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel). And [getting ~400 rep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4897144/shruti1810?tab=reputation) by simply adding the tag should be rejected.

Comment: They are not harmless, they waste the time of reviewers.

Comment: Tag-only edits don't give you rep, do they? Or do they just not count toward the badge?

Comment: @TylerH: they give you rep, just like any other edit.

Comment: It could potentially add information to the question, if (as it usually does) it means a question about the Excel object model. That meaning has nothing specifically VBA about it. See [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300056/rename-or-otherwise-replace-foo-vba-to-foo-object-model).

Answer (score 17):

The equation CAN be true, but is not **necessarily** true.

Example question:

> I have an excel document that I want to programmatically import into
>   my MS Access DB using vba in Access. The (fictional) `ImportXML()`
>   function is giving me the "xyz" error.

Tags:  [msaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/msaccess) [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel)

This is not [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba) .. the user is writing vba is MS Access.

Comment: Is this tagged [tag:msaccess] because the code happens to be in Access? Or because the destination is an Access database?

Comment: Am I using [tag:jet]/[tag:ms-jet-ace]? [tag:ado]? [tag:linked-tables]? [Direct SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177907(v=office.12).aspx)? Any one of these is more important than which VBA host I am in.

Comment: If I am iterating cell by cell (say because I need to read the cell formatting while importing), why should this not be tagged [tag:excel-vba]? How is it any different from doing the exact same thing in a VBA module contained in an Excel workbook (which presumably would be tagged [tag:excel-vba])?

Comment: Yes, but this is a example question about MS Access using VBA what's the point of Excel being there? It has no bearing on the question. The tags should be [tag:msaccess] [tag:vba]. The issue here is not the equation more the OPs understanding of what is relevant to the question.