# Edits to add a compound tag

Tags: discussion, tags

A question contains tags [foo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foo) and [bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bar).  A suggested edit adds [foo-bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foo-bar).  Is this appropriate/necessary/desired?

I'm choosing to call [foo-bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foo-bar) a *compound tag*.  Sometimes, the compound tag is more descriptive than its individual parts and should replace one of them ([eg:](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8622976) [linux-kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux-kernel)).  In others, it seems to add no new information to the question beyond the two base tags (eg: [android-spinner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-spinner), or [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba)).  I've never seen a case where I believe it's useful to have all three.

I come across this situation occasionally when reviewing suggested edits.  Usually I've ignored the tag change and based my review on the other content in the edits, but I would like to know the right way to review these edits.  In general, *How much value is there in including a compound tag alongside one or both of its component parts?*

Comment: related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295302/is-this-implication-true-excel-vba-excel-vba

Comment: To reply to the asker's examples, "android-spinner" might differentiate it from other kinds of spinners. The "android" tag should still be there in the question. A compound tag that would be superfluous would be one that adds no value per se. "c#-express" for example, is (was) just a lite version of a product that MS released back in the day, it didn't have anything exclusive that was not in regular C#.

Answer (score 2):

From [an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93773/289691) from 2011 to [How should "compound" tags be handled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93607/289691)

> The sad truth is that the powers that be don't really care how tags
> go. In a sense they are right to not care too, search tools are
> usually what should be used to get to a question, not so much tagging.
> There are far more pressing matters to them than tagging.
>
> Trust me, most (if not all) re-tagging of this nature and attempts at
> sensible nomenclature end up as [community efforts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62545/please-help-me-eliminate-year-tags-and-dangling-version-numbers), not site
> policy. Part of the problem comes from tag creation, which is for SO
> at this point too open a process, and it's too easy to create tags
> unknowingly.
>
> The worsts case of tag "compounding", in a sense, is [vb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb) and
> [.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net) versus [vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb.net), as well as the various "-express" tags
> where the "-express" part is actually not key to the issue but just
> part of the asker's environment. At the same time you don't want an
> [express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/express) tag floating around just for that. (Even if there now is
> an express tag but in the sense of MVC framework for Node.js.)