# Let's stop tag wiki plagiarism

Tags: discussion, review-queues, plagiarism, review-suspension

Due to the amount of support this has received, I've posted a follow up: [Stopping tag wiki plagiarism, Part II: Taking Action](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318288/1849664).

---

> **tl;dr**: We have a problem with plagiarism. Let's make it clear to editors and reviewers that plagiarism is Not Okay, and that reviewers are expected to check for it.
>
> Also, **let's set a policy of temporarily review-banning reviewers who approve blatant plagiarism.**

Stack Overflow has a problem with plagiarism in tag wikis (and tag wiki excerpts). How do I know? Well:

1. I just opened the suggested edit queue history and scrolled through looking for edits to tag wikis. The third one I found was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10697198). Guess what? [It's copied from php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php).
2. My go-to technique for finding these: Writing a SEDE query to list all tag wikis and excerpts... **then ordering it randomly**. It should be much, much harder than this... but the plagiarism is everywhere.

Plagiarism [is Not Okay](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/134715/215468). We should do what we can to keep it off our site.

Therefore, I propose we take two actions:

> 1. Let's make it clear to both editors and reviewers that plagiarism is Not Okay.

According to [the privilege page for approving tag-wiki edits](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits), reviewers need to "ensure" that *"All the content is original or attributed properly"*. This means that they should, at least, copy a few sentences out of a tag wiki into Google (in quotes, for literal matching) before approving. Approving these is Not Okay. We'll come back to that.

Let's add some text to the "What are Tag Wikis" sidebar shown to editors when suggesting an edit specifying, in bold text, that plagiarism is Not Okay.

Next, let's make it clear to reviewers in the queue that they are expected to check for plagiarism. I'm actually considering proposing making reviewers confirm that they checked for plagiarism before approving a tag wiki. I'm not sold on the implementation, though - as long as it's text somewhere that reviewers will read.

> 2. Let's set a precedent that approving obvious plagiarism *will* get you a break from review.

I believe that the only way we can really curb this disease is to make sure reviewers are doing their job - remember [the privilege page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits)? *"When approving these edits, ensure that: All the content is original or attributed properly*"

Reviewers that approve content copied verbatim from Wikipedia, a project page, or anything else the editor didn't write *aren't reviewing correctly*.

"Not reviewing correctly" is simply another term for **"abuse".** Approving these edits is actively harming the site. We can't tolerate that.

Let's set a precedent that anyone who approves obvious plagiarism (as determined by a moderator) is **instantly eligible for an *x*-day review ban**.

I honestly believe that this is the only way we can stop the influx of plagiarized content - our contribution filter isn't working, so let's fix it.

**But I don't want to check for plagiarism, it's too much work!** I completely understand - and you don't have to review tag wikis. It's that simple: If a user isn't willing to put in the work required to do a job correctly, there are plenty of others that are. You're completely welcome to skip the wikis, of course, which represent a minority of the reviews in that queue.

Thoughts?

Comment: You asked for thoughts, so here's mine: Nothing will happen. Sorry for the pessimism.

Comment: @Deduplicator Can you elaborate a little? Will nothing happen because this won't be implemented, or will nothing happen if this *is* implemented?

Comment: The former, though I will celebrate if being surprised on that score.

Comment: I feel like #1 is... kinda weak sauce. If the folks editing these are under the impression that plagiarism is *acceptable*, we have bigger problems; the more likely cause is that **they don't realize they're plagiarizing.** If you think guidance will help here, suggest something that explains (for instance) that copying a product page or wiki is seen as dishonest. IOW, educate rather than just shouting - if we wanna shout at folks, #2 is a much better bullhorn.

Comment: @Shog9 I'd agree with that - I'll try to write something up tomorrow

Comment: Related http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238339/213575

Comment: @Shog9 well, they won't know because there's nobody that tell them is not ok. They don't read the help center, nor guidance. Sadly, the only way forward is with the mace of rejection and that has to start with reviewers. And those reviewers were the ones that suggested or saw plagiarism being accepted. Kind of a vicious circle we got here.

Comment: @Shog Again, as with regular edit reviewing, the guidance for tag wiki edit reviewing is lacking. People aren't told what to look for to reject an edit, so their process is "do I like it? If not, choose reject reason" instead of "does it match any reject reason or is otherwise harmful? If so, reject with that reason".

Comment: Just gonna throw this out there: the current reputation threshold for reviewing these edits is 5000; there's no reason that can't be changed though. The reputation threshold for editing these wikis *without* approval is 20000 after all...

Comment: @Shog9 Raising that could definitely help, but I do think it would need to be combined with enforcing plagiarism checks in some way or another - I've seen 20, 30, 40kers approve these. We've seen that after a certain point, reputation stops becoming a decent measure of trust and starts becoming a measure of how much you know about a subject matter - not how good you are at moderation tasks.

Comment: "Stack Overflow has a problem with plagiarism" full stop. (I know, this topic is focused on tag wikis, but you can't talk about plagiarism without being unnecessarily pedantic.)

Comment: "**But I don't want to check for plagiarism, it's too much work!** I completely understand - and you don't have to review tag wikis. If a user isn't willing to put in the work required to do a job correctly, there are plenty of others that are." But it's not fair that they get to earn the Steward badge and I don't!

Comment: @Shog9: You're only saying that because the only thing that can be implemented as a system are reputation thresholds, and not because you actually think reputation is a reliable measure of a person's ethics, right?

Comment: I'm saying it because if we're looking at blocking a whole bunch of people from reviewing, we might wanna see how that actually breaks down, @BoltClock. There are a few other places in review where the system lets you recommend an action you don't have the reputation to actually perform yet, but with a **15 thousand reputation** difference between approving and *doing*, tag wiki reviews are a distinct anomaly; I'd be surprised if there wasn't a stark difference in behavior at some threshold in there.

Comment: @Shog9: Ah, I missed that.

Comment: Relevant: [Number of tag-wiki suggested edit reviews done per 1k rep bucket](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/416499#graph). It looks like <20kers do the majority of the reviews, although we could probably afford to raise the threshold nonetheless.

Comment: Take a look at [Merry Go Round Situation](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305546/merry-go-round-situation). There are some suggestions for changing who gets served tag-wiki edits in there, though not about changing the rep-threshold (many in my answer).

Comment: Just a thought... How practical would presenting results from Google searches for random literal wiki quotes during the review be? I don't expect that determining if it's actual plagiarism could easily be automated (that's why we need reviewers), but putting the google results in the reviewer's face might help trigger an appropriate action.

Comment: Why not? Unless there's some license forbidding copy/pasting the source, what EXACTLY do you get from inventing your own way to say the same? I thought only SEO "industry" ever cared about tricks like that.

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov Plagiarism is theft, and nearly everything has a license (express or implied) forbidding theft.

Comment: @undo, you might as well write "plagiarism is rape" or "plagiarism is genocide". Sorry, but plagiarism is only plagiarism. And short concise execrpt are protected by fair use laws pretty much all around the world.

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov No, plagiarism is not rape nor genocide. Synonyms for plagiarism: [appropriation, infringement, piracy, counterfeiting; theft](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/plagiarism?s=t).

Comment: @undo, just stop this pathetic word games. I can open that same site too: synonym for  infringement is violation and that's rape! OMFG! I can also reach sin and prostitution with just two more open tabs. Plagiarism is neither of those.

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov Also, note that plagiarism isn't necessarily the breaking of copyright. Copyright and fair use are legal systems, while plagiarism leans toward the moral side. A wise man once said, *"The law isn't moral, but that doesn't mean people don't have to be moral."*

Comment: @Undo, I don't want your morals if they're about that copy/pasting short excerpts for community use without any profit to copy/paster himself is immoral.

Comment: [Not a new problem, and not specific to Stack Overflow (why didn't you post on MSE?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102314/can-we-do-anything-against-tag-wikis-copy-pasted-from-wikipedia).

Comment: @Undo Re. rep buckets: at <10k, there's a top bar indicator for suggested edits, After 10k the top bar indicator changes its meaning to “there may or may not be something for you in any of the review queues”, so it's pretty natural that >10kers review suggested edits a lot less.

Comment: @Gilles I didn't post on mSE because I see this problem most on SO, and the crux of the proposal is to review ban people approving these - which I don't think needs to be a network-wide thing.

Comment: Yes, plagiarism is plagiarism, @Oleg. This has been discussed many times over the years and the consensus is that folks on SO do not like plagiarism. We even [added a policy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83955/plagiarism-should-be-addressed-specifically-in-the-faq) at the community's request [condemning it and laying out guidance for avoiding it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing). Plagiarists in other areas of the site frequently find their posts deleted and their accounts suspended; there's no reason to expect different treatment in wikis.

Comment: Perhaps the answer is not in making sure that the tag reviewers are responsible for recognizing that a tag has been plagiarized, but a change needs to be made to tag creation/edits to require a citation link.  If we are required to come up with our own words for each tag, how many times does that tag then get moderately distorted from the original intent of what the tag represents.  As we can see from all the comments above, words have many synonyms and can drastically change the meaning.  Tags may need to be restructured so it contains various standard fields (about, standards, FAQ, etc).

Comment: @JabberwockyDecompiler: The fact that the content is plagiarized is often not the worst part about it, even though that alone is already unacceptable. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/309384

Comment: @Deduplicator Agreed, there is a problem. Per [plagiarism.org](http://www.plagiarism.org/citing-sources/whats-a-citation) all you need is a citation. Paraphrasing is nice, but with tag revisions say v1 was a paraphrase, v2 was a paraphrase of v1, and so on, it is possible to get the 10M monkeys that type Shakespere and end up with the same text (unintentionally). Correct citation will show users where the text came from, then the SO community can decide to modify if necessary. Note: you should also cite if you paraphrase.

Comment: It would help if there were any mechanism to *remove* plagiarised tag wiki content once it's posted, but when I've [tried to edit it out](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8268695) I've had my edits rejected. Most reviewers seem to actively prefer plagiarised content to none, sadly.

Comment: @MarkAmery Definitely. I generally tend to flag one of the suggester's posts, in hopes that a moderator will just roll it back and send a note to the user. I haven't had great luck rolling them back on my own either.

Comment: In a [related post on MSO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208148/235005), @TimPost just seemed to think the mods needed to prioritize this, communicating with the offenders as quickly as possible.  2 years later...

Comment: Some of the suggested edits are absurd. For plagiarism to be plagiarism, there needs to be sufficient content to be sure it is not just a general usage of things. For example http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11081582 considers "Method belonging to a utility class." to be plagiarized from wikipedia, while it is simply the rephrase of "utility-method" (the tag).

Comment: @Shog9 I'm going to need some community manager support for [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315815/3956566) as there is an attitude that a zero voted answer does not form a consensus and some people prefer to [leave the plagiarised content there](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11081724), rather than accept a generic wiki tag excerpt. It takes a lot of time to go through these and to have community support and SO management support would make it easier, thanks.

Comment: Users have now started removing plagiarized content from wiki tags. I came across an edit where contents copied from Wikepedia was deleted. I am no laywer, however, looking at the Wikipedia page on reusing content, Wikipedia does seem to allow re-use of content provided it is correctly attributed. Rather than deleting the content, wouldn't it be better to correctly attribute it ? This is the Wiki page on content reuse: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Reusing_Wikipedia_content

Comment: @Jaco That could work, but even attributed Wikipedia content is almost never exactly what we wasn't in a good tag wiki. I'm of the opinion (and my opinion doesn't matter much) that it's better to remove it entirely in hopes that someone sees the blank space and writes an original, nicely fitting one. That might be over optimistic, though.

Comment: @MarkR I agree with you on that one, we can't say for certain it's plagiarism. I probably wouldn't have suggested that edit myself, but I did approve it because it's an overall improvement to the excerpt.

Comment: Isn't better to rewrite  the tag wiki documentation rather than deleting it all ? And what if a Wikipedia editor copies text from Stack overflow instead of the other way around?

Comment: @Jaco I check for the latter case by going back in the Wikipedia revision history; I've never found a case of that yet. And yes, it's definitely better to rewrite it - but only if one has the expertise to do so without completely butchering the subject. No one here is an expert in everything, but if someone wants to help out by removing plagiarized stuff (or correctly attributing it, if we decide to go that route)... that's a net good for the site.

Comment: If you don't have 20K, you might be better off just creating a list of these for others to work on, @MsYvette. For the actual *wikis*, it's trivial to add attribution OR replace the contents with something more useful, but for *excerpts* this is overkill; we're talking about a line of text. Much less overhead for someone with full editing rights to just edit these directly.

Comment: @Jaco the stuff from wikipedia is usually derived from other sources and wikipedia then attributes that appropriately, if you do a search you can see the content is taken from elsewhere, in a wikipedia copy and paste, it can be difficult to post all the original sources. Yeh and rewriting it, is not easy unless you understand the tag. Mind you, you are most welcome to do this and so are others.

Comment: @Shog9 sure, except I only know of one user with over 20k rep willing to assist. When the wiki excerpt is a direct copy and paste from elsewhere, word for word, are you happy to leave it there?

Comment: Ping me in the tavern or something, @msyv

Comment: @Shog9 can't find the tavern O.O

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376638/plagiarised-tag-info-of-webdeploy

Answer (score 28):

The biggest sources of plagiarism that I've seen (although not necessarily here on Stack Overflow), is from Wikipedia. Regardless of where something is plagiarized from, here are some tips to help catch it:

Here's some of the easiest ways to catch it:

- Look for the `[` and the `]`.

  If you see random braces, especially if they've got numbers between them (e.g. `[51]`), there is a good chance that the wiki was plagiarized. These are the in-line references that Wikipedia employs, to cite the content that makes their articles.
- Look if something seems to 'continue' at the beginning.

  I found this once: (emphasis mine)

  > The DMCA **also** criminalizes circumvention of access control, regardless of actual copyright infringement...

  That was at the beginning of a tag wiki. The fact that the first sentence started with the word 'also' signalled that it was a separate paragraph, communicating another idea. It was also a sign of plagiarism.
- Look for 'raw links'

  Look for raw links that aren't formatted at all. Just like this: http://stackoverflow.com

  The fact that they are not formatted to begin with should already be a signal for improvement, but they may also just be a poor form of citing: A simple copy/paste for content, and just a copy/paste of the link as well. Check the link, see if the content is copied.
- Check for 'mass edits'

  In my experience, a lot of plagiarism comes from people who suggest multiple wikis within quick succession. If you notice a lot of tag wikis coming in quickly, and from one person, take an extra look. Similar to how you may raise a flag for many low quality edits, this may be worth a custom moderator flag, so that a moderator can intervene and take appropriate action.

---

In response to the proposal, it's important to make a note that plagiarism can be relatively hard to catch. If one can try, and visibly make an effort to catch it, then that's good for the reviewer.

I also want to say that this does not mean *you're never allowed to quote things*. Quoting is good! Just make sure that the majority of your edit is not quoted content, and that you include a link to the source. Something like this is even okay:

> From [blah blah blah] (link):
>
> *insert quoted content here*

or even...

> yabadabadoo... (*quoted content*)
>
> [Article/Source title - Don't just use the word "source"] (link)

Comment: This would be a nice answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102314/can-we-do-anything-against-tag-wikis-copy-pasted-from-wikipedia)

Comment: This misses the most important point: any time you're reviewing a tag wiki edit, paste some phrases from it into Google. Seriously, every single time. *Most* of them are plagiarised.

Comment: @MarkAmery You're right. I did it with "blah blah blah". It's from Kesha. Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blah_Blah_Blah_%28Kesha_song%29.

Answer (score 10):

Posting a late answer after [this discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/28454270#28454270) in chat with [Undo](http://www.stackoverflow.com/users/1849664/undo) in the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers). I'm helping to query wiki tag edits and check for plagiarism. If I find the content is plagiarized, I will attempt to edit the wiki to be original content from my brain, with any quoted content to have appropriate attribution.

After [more discussion](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4519029#4519029) in [the tavern](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta).

Plagiarised excerpts will be starred in a separate [spreadsheet](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4519030#4519030) for a [user with >20k](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4519036#4519036) to go through and update. Unless the excerpt is an identical plagiarised match to the wiki and in my wiki edit it is simple to update with an original excerpt.

---

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11090150) is an example, with plagiarised content from [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/intro?hl=en).
Screenshot:

[image]

Or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11090130) With plagiarised content from [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Custom-Loaders-for-Windows-afba8c00).
Screenshot:

[image]

Searching on [Google](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=A%20suffix%20is%20something%20added%20at%20the%20end%20of%20a%20word%20that%20conditions%20its%20usage%20or%20meaning.&oq=A%20suffix%20is%20something%20added%20at%20the%20end%20of%20a%20word%20that%20conditions%20its%20usage%20or%20meaning.&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64l2.408j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) the following:

---

This post serves as a heads up so I can link to this post in my edit reason, to avoid conflicts with other users. My edit reason will read as follow:

> removed plagiarised content from  -link-
> please see meta post https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315815/3956566

Comment: Wrong link, your edit-suggestions are at http://stackoverflow.com/users/3956566/ms-yvette?tab=activity&sort=suggestions

Comment: Why not to add source link from where it was used/found?

Comment: Some sources, in particular Wikipedia, do appear to allow re-use of content provided it is correctly attributed. Rather than deleting the content, wouldn't it be better to correctly attribute it, at least if the original source allows this?

Comment: @Jaco some of the wiki sources are actually taken from other sources and attributed properly in wikipedia. Some have several sources from wikipedia.

Comment: @kenorb yes, I have wondered about that. It some cases that it easily done, as it's taken from docs from one place, in other cases there are several sources (but it's been taken from wikipedia), but I can see the sources.. and to be honest, there's so many plagiarised tags, it would take so long to correctly attribute some of these. As it is it takes a while. It's whether the objective is to get rid of plagiarised content quickly or improve the tags.. improving the tags is harder, as it requires a degree of expertise/knowledge in/of that tag.

Comment: There's no reason other people on here can't assist with this. It's all good to suggest to others, improve your efforts to help clean up the site, it's better to help :)

Answer (score 5):

Don't allow any wikipedia content, only links to articles.  The main content of the pages should be about **how the tag is used on stack overflow**.  Require reviewers to provide a source of plagiarism and if the edit is approved, it should be flagged for further review.  You should give a badge to the person who found the plagiarism.

---

The tag wiki's are suppose to be about how the subject/tag relates to stack overflow and not an encyclopedia article.  No one will plagiarize an article on how a topic/tag relates to stack overflow because such an article is unlikely to exist.  People shouldn't approve wikipedia content as it really isn't helpful to see what kind of Q/A belongs with a tag.  If people only approved by this guide line, then I don't think that most plagiarism would exist.

A [single reviewer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174388/shouldnt-wiki-review-rejects-of-plagarism-have-a-source) might find plagiarism, but the current system will not act on it.  This is fairly intelligent as the reviewer isn't required to provide any source that they believe was infringed.

People also *learn by example*.  The fact that we have so many tag pages with wikipedia content makes it seem that this is okay.  In fact, if wikipedia is cited as a source, it is okay; just not without attribution by my understanding.  Changing it so there was no wikipedia (or other attributed content) would give no people examples of this as being okay (and missing the fact it was attributed and this is important).

Comment: I suggested something somewhat similar a while back: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/201884/215468, but that requires a structural change (read: developer time), and thus is less likely to be implemented than a policy. I'd much rather have this built into the system as you suggest, though.

Comment: This is just wrong. Tag wikis aren't *solely* for how to use a tag, but they are for *what the topic of the tag is about*. Guidance on how to use a tag belongs in the excerpt. Quoting is not, and should never be an issue. Tag wikis aren't a full-out article, but they should have enough information to answer *What is [tag]?, where is [tag] used? What's cool about [tag]?* and so on.

Comment: @Zizouz212  I was not suggesting *solely* for how to use a tag, but there should be information on *how to use a tag*... I said *main content*; in the OPs example, there is nothing about tags at all (also a strong indicator that it is could be copied from somewhere).

Comment: @undo  I know it is work to implement this and thanks for the link to your post.  I guess that when you can show having this type of entry gives many benefits instead of just one, it is more likely to be done.  I do think that rewarding a reviewer for finding plagiarism is better than punishing people for not seeing it.

Answer (score -10):

Make a greasemonkey script or similar tool to help the tag wiki reviewer. The script should flag close search hits and insist that the reviewer checks attribution.

Comment: It would be helpful if voters would comment, but such is life. I see that automated searches are unpopular, but I don't know if they are unpopular with people who like copy-pasta, or those who hate it.

Answer (score -24):

Instead of making reviewers' life harder, we could think of an easy way to insert the attribution with the tags? change the parser so that such tag doesn't go without an attribution?

Comment: An automated way to do this would be ideal, but it's harder than it looks. Not all wikis are copied from somewhere, so just requiring a link won't work. Google gets a little touchy about automated searches, so that won't work without substantial effort forging an agreement with them, which probably won't happen.

Comment: Maybe a form with an area for a text, and a field for attribution which is mandatory, unless the user checks a checkbox that's labeled "The text is my original work and not copied from any source". Checking it would make the attribution field non-mandatory, but also add a note to reviewers "User has chosen to waive attribution, please check if the content is indeed original" or something. It's not magic, but it will work for people who just copy-paste and aren't aware that attribution is necessary, and will draw attention to intentional plagiarism.

Comment: @Undo said "Google gets a little touchy about automated searches", but there are other search engines with public search APIs. Wikipedia has its own plagiarism and copyright bots and scripts, and StackOverflow should too.

Comment: I feel like 20+ downvotes is a little bit unjustified ; the idea had merit. Having a field, either in the markup or in a form or whatever doesn't matter, as long as it is bringing to people's attention (or reminding) that attribution is important. I'm certain that it would be enough to change the proportion of non-attributed quotations.

Comment: The problem is that there is no such easy way as you ask for in the answer. What RealSkeptic suggested is much more doable, but we up/down-vote answers and comments on answers separately.

Comment: As @artless noise commented, tag wikis should mostly be about how the tag is used on SO.  A brief summary and link to wikipedia for more detail is typically good.  A chunk of copy/pasted text from a wiki article is usually not a *good* tag wiki anyway, so this solves the wrong problem.  Also, "insert the attribution with the tags"?  We're talking about the info wiki for a single tag.  Such as https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info