# Only optionally show tag wiki edits in suggested edit reviews

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

I fell into the same trap as @Trix ([7 day ban for plagiarism found in tag edit review](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344964/7-day-ban-for-plagiarism-found-in-tag-edit-review)) and just read the [Stopping tag wiki plagiarism, Part II: Taking Action](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318288/stopping-tag-wiki-plagiarism-part-ii-taking-action) message @Trix' answer was marked a duplicate of.

In the light of such drastic measures after not recognizing a copy of some definitively non-creative, merely short descriptive sentence from some documentation site, I don't want to review tag wikis edit suggestions anymore.

I'm still interested in reviewing other edit suggestions, though. But when going through the suggested edits, I often after the first few entries get shown only tag edit suggestions.

Would it be possible to add some option to not be shown tag edit suggestions, merely regular question or answer or documentation edits? After all similar review queue subdivisions exist for other queues (was it close or re-open? Due to the review suspension I cannot check), too.

Comment: Non wiki edits can still contain copied stuff. I would be much more interested in sending more of those possible copied content stuff to you as you're more likely to review those correctly, given your recent experience.

Comment: @rene When reviewing stuff, I'm not interested in checking for plagiarism but for improving the value of a question and answer for future readers. If that is not welcome, I'll just stop reviewing altogether.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. As this probably needs 6 to 8 weeks to be implemented would a userscript that disable all review buttons except skip work for you?

Comment: For a few weeks I can also recognize and skip all tag edit suggestions without support of such a script, in particular as there is no need for this for this week after all... as long as I have a hope that this is a temporary work-around. ;)

Comment: You can always have hope ... I'm not going to disappoint you upfront ...

Comment: i don't think you need to put _Feature idea_ in the title when you tag it with *feature-request*

Comment: @Tanner strictly speaking yes. I'll edit it out.

Comment: I still think that tag wiki/excerpt edits should be in their own queue.

Comment: FP and LA queues can separate questions and answers. That's probably what you're thinking of.

Comment: I am not a big fan of reviews (sorry), but if I do one, I am paying maximum attention. If I would see something like "tag wiki" I'd simply instantly hit `Skip`. There is no need to improve anything. You got trapped by attempting doing something you shouldn't do. Please don't.