# Make Suggested Edits queue filterable for posts vs tag wikis

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, suggested-edits

As a reviewer for the [Suggested Edits](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits) queue, I am confronted with two very distinct types of review:

1. The suggested edits on Posts:

   - Posts account for [the most visible data](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/03/09/anyone-actually-visit-stack-overflows-home-page/) of Stack Overflow (the core of Q&A), so they need to be dealt quickly and [they have a low maximum of queued items](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345125/suggested-edit-queue-is-full) making this queue (I'm guessing) the fastest, together with *First Posts*
   - suggested edits are made by people with 0 to 1,999 Reputation
   - they can be voted on, or improved/replaced directly from the queue, when you have 2,000 Reputation (or unilaterally by the post owner, if they are not suspended)
   - they shall not conflict with author's intent
   - eyes should be opened for not breaking/adding anything (except relevant tags)
2. The suggested edits on Tags wiki/Usage guides:

   - Tag info accounts for far fewer visits, so (I'm guessing) they wouldn't reduce Stack Overflow's popularity, if handled slower than Posts
   - suggested edits are made by people with 1 to 19,999 Reputation
   - they can only be voted on when you have 5,000 Reputation and improved/replaced directly from the queue when you have 20,000 Reputation
   - they can fully redefine the previous content (which could even have been empty)
   - they often come as two independent edits where one is likely bad, because if wiki or usage guide is previously empty, you can't edit one part without completing the other part, which is of a very different nature and where many fall into a trap
   - eyes should be opened for copyright issues and confusion between definition and usage guidance

Reviewing Posts and Tags wiki/Usage guide being so different and requiring different mindset:

#### I'd like a filter by type.

Comment: Very related: [Only optionally show tag wiki edits in suggested edit reviews](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344997/2675154).

Comment: Fun fact: the original editor of any given tag wiki gets unilateral approve/reject votes just like the author of a regular post, but *doesn't* get notified and therefore doesn't automatically have a link to the review. (This is [probably a bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168852/the-user-who-first-proposed-a-tag-wiki-is-treated-as-owner-for-suggested-edits).)

Comment: @NathanTuggy I use count value `0` to denote anonymous edits

Comment: _suggested edits are made by people with 0 to 1,999 Reputation_ What about anonymous editors(edit by guests)?

Comment: Until I reached 5k recently, I thought it is implemented like that. It was a big surprise for me that it is not. So, yes. I am in.

Comment: Duplicate on meta.stackexchange.com: [Can we have tag wiki and wiki excerpt edit reviews in a separate queue to suggested edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277031/can-we-have-tag-wiki-and-wiki-excerpt-edit-reviews-in-a-separate-queue-to-sugges). Please give that post some attention, maybe post your suggestions as an answer there too.

Comment: [Related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/348024/4639281)