# Suggested Edits are taking longer and longer to tackle

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

I constantly see the Suggested Edits queue being at roughly 195/200. Best we may do is handling 20 votes a day/reviewer. But I got the feeling that the queue is actually cluttered with some suggested edits that very few want/can handle. The kind of edits that stay many days in the queue. And this is true for recent tag wiki edits:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15782055 took about 9 days to review
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15642483 took about 8 days to review
- [This pending suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15822646) simply wants to remove copyrighted material ([stolen from here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/speech/sfspeechrecognizer)), but is already 5 days old.

Would it be possible to solve the increasing cluttering?

- Maybe removing wiki edits from the 200 limit?
- Maybe allowing to sort the suggested edits by date, to focus on old ones?

Related:
[Preventing suggested edit queue being frequently full?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346065/preventing-suggested-edit-queue-being-frequently-full)

Comment: There have been a few discussions about this recently. It definitely seems like something needs to change. Keep in mind that only 5k-ers can review tag wiki edits, and many users skip those reviews due to the fact that you're expected to search for plagiarism and such when reviewing tag wiki edits. You may also want to include a URL of where the content was copied from to support such edits in the future.

Comment: I must say that the recent cases were reviewers were banned because they approved plagiarism surely doesn't help either. And I did 40 reviews in that queue yesterday where I found myself skipping tag wiki's if I wasn't 100% sure if it was original work but couldn't find a source on Google.

Comment: This seems to have gotten a lot worse with the top-bar redesign. I was hoping to see some improvement with the change in how we display the indicator a week ago, but... I suspect we've altered the dynamics of this permanently by not restricting < 10K users to ONLY the suggested edit count.

Comment: @Shog9, One of the problems was that the badge was displayed *all* the time. When that happens, people start ignoring the fact that the badge is there. Badges like that, which are effectively notifications, should be displayed only when some exceptional condition exists (e.g. one or more queues are above some set threshold, a threshold that does not occur a high percentage of the time). The badge should also not be displayed to users who have completed their possible reviews in the queue which is particularly impacted.

Comment: Overall, if there is a review queue that never gets depleted, then there is a problem. I think we could free up review resources if we got rid of the fuzzy 'meta' queues "help and improvement" and "triage" that only aims to shuffle reviews between different queues. Reviewers must waste a lot of time on those, that would be better used on the reviews that have direct impact on the site, such as suggested edits.

Comment: @rene: I do think that a factor is being review-banned for not spotting plagiarism. That is wholly counter-productive. It happened to me; I was so annoyed that I did no reviews for a month or more. If SO doesn't like me trying to help the site, I don't need to do the gunky, unrewarding, unrewarded, hard work of reviewing. I think you should earn multiple gold badges in each queue to say "thank you for continuing to do the drudgery that keeps SO clean". As it stands, the reward system says "once you've done enough reviews for a gold badge, you can stop — we're never going to thank you again".

Comment: At the risk of sound incredibly unaware, where exactly is the expectation set that tag wiki edits are supposed to be checked for plagiarism?  There certainly doesn't appear to be anything on the Suggested Edits review page itself.

Comment: @DavidL It doesn't need to I think, it is in the [Terms of Service](https://stackexchange.com/legal) you are held to once you sign-up. See section 3, right?

Comment: @rene I think nearly everyone here operates under the assumption that plagiarism is bad and I hope that as a collective we never tolerate it.  That said, the tone I see in this question is disturbing...that if you do not ***actively prove to the best of your ability*** that  a wiki tag was not plagiarized, that you are subject to a ban.  This is news to me and I'll be skipping wiki tag suggested edits from now on if that's the case.

Comment: I think what changed here is that *assume good faith* has been proven to be a wrong operation condition, at least for me. On the plus side: My grumpy side can now be on the loose , rejecting all the thingz ...

Comment: To clarify, I'm not advocating for laxer standards. I'm simply asking for clearer, well-documented expectations. :)

Comment: @DavidL Any time you are approving new content (such as with Docs.SO proposals), you should be checking for plagiarism. It is also very helpful to note that most plagiarized tag wiki suggestions [don't make very good tag wikis / excerpts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214337/what-is-a-tag-wiki-how-do-i-write-a-good-one).

Comment: @TinyGiant that certainly seems more than reasonable but how is that being communicated to users?  It isn't obvious and it is an ***inferred*** responsibility instead of an ***explicitly instructed*** responsibility. That to me is a quality issue just waiting to explode.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See my answer here: [Is the top bar redesign the sole cause of the suggested edit slowdown?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349118/is-the-top-bar-redesign-the-sole-cause-of-the-suggested-edit-slowdown)

There are a few possible solutions here, including one really easy one that I've just put into place. We'll see how it works.

Comment: Perhaps a TL;DR and an official answer is *So I've done that - effective immediately, suggested edits require only 2 reviews to complete on Stack overflow*?

Answer (score 71):

Tag wiki and excerpt edits should have a queue of their own for a few reasons:

1. Tag wiki / excerpt edits require some effort be put forth to determine if the content is plagiarized.
2. Tag wiki / excerpt edits require that the reviewer knows what makes up [a good tag wiki / excerpt](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214337/what-is-a-tag-wiki-how-do-i-write-a-good-one), this is not the same as what makes up a good post.
3. The ability to review such edits comes at a higher reputation level, and there is very little indication that a user can now start reviewing tag wiki edits, or even that they are reviewing such an edit.

Comment: How about a filter?

Comment: @rene while that may help, I don't think it would be sufficient to solve the problems that currently exist with regards to reviewing tag wiki / excerpt edits.

Comment: [Can we have tag wiki and wiki excerpt edit reviews in a separate queue to suggested edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277031/can-we-have-tag-wiki-and-wiki-excerpt-edit-reviews-in-a-separate-queue-to-sugges)

Comment: Can any person with badge in the given tag and the required rep be shown a inbox link to the tag wiki edit review they are qualified to do?

Answer (score 4):

This is actually [already implemented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281202/243821)! Thanks and sorry Shog9 for making me realize it!

---

There should be a limit of concurrent suggested edits *per user*, I think of 5 to 10.

It would, as a glorious side effect, prevent suggested edit sprees that mostly result in meta questions and/or rep farming.

It would have an effect on the actual filling of the suggested edit queue, maybe we wouldn't even have to raise it or make separate edits queues (even though I do think it is a good idea).

And maybe people (this is my magical thinking in action), that want to suggest edits, knowing that they have a limit, would make each of them only when they really can substantially improve a question, to improve their chances of it being accepted.

Comment: I think that canceling the `+2` extra rep will have a better effect - Leas uses will try to earn quick & easy precious reputation points

Comment: Yeah, that sounds reasonable, but I am divided on that. It's becoming more and more difficult for new users to actually answer a first question and get reputation, so having a way to edit posts and gain whatever small reputation from it doesn't seem like it should disappear altogether because of the people that abuse it.

Comment: I understand, but it attract minor changes that we can do without, and when you say _It's becoming more and more difficult for new users to actually answer a first question and get reputation_ - How exactly did you get your nice reputation? I don't see any mass edits on your [first activity log](http://stackoverflow.com/users/576767/f%C3%A9lix-gagnon-grenier?tab=reputation&sort=time&page=10) `:)` So it might be more difficult to earn reputation, but that's because you actually must use your brain for that, and for some user (not you BTW) it's definitely not an easy thing to do

Comment: This already exists: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210416/rate-limit-suggested-edits/281202#281202

Comment: *facepalm* oh well...

Comment: @Shog9 maybe we could reduce it to 4 or 3 per user on Stack Overflow for a few days?

Comment: I'm not sure it would make any difference, @Cœur. Gotta look at the data here & see what's actually holding it up.

Comment: @AlonEitan Not sure how common this is but pretty much all my SO rep is suggested edits. FWIW I end up spending most of it on downvoting bad/misleading answers, it's not exactly a booming rep business. I've said this before but having experience mostly in mature tech can make it hard to find new, non-dupe stuff to answer... there's a lot I could do on CR but SO's been tricky for me.

Comment: @jrh I have no problem with the fact that people edit and get reputation, I have a problem with [minor](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15897878), [meaningless](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15897871) [and](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15897993) [unneccacery](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15895351) [edits](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15888715) which i'm sure are all for that extra `+2` rep

Comment: @AlonEitan I get that but it's a little counter-intuitive, and there's some meta posts that actually encourage those sort of edits (I'll find some examples later). Personally I know to avoid doing those sort of things but the technical writer / nitpicker part of me still thinks "This is the face of this site for people landing here from Google and we're just going to let lzy mspllings sit on this site forever?" What if high rep users never come back to fix these things?  Comments don't work that often, and it's too minor for a mod flag, so is it worth preserving mistakes forever?

Comment: @jrh Of course not, and I'm sure you're doing good job with those edits (Since, as you said, most of your rep is based on your suggested edits, and your general approach for submitting edits), but when I review pending edits it sometime remind me the [first days of the documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328491/10-reputation-for-topic-editing-is-too-high) - There was a reputation frenzy that stopped only when the "free prizes" were cancelled, which made people not the submit whichever minor change in order to get easy rep on every example upvote

Answer (score -20):

> Suggested Edits are taking longer and longer to tackle

No, suggested tag wiki/excerpt edits take longer. Why? Well, because **they should take longer.**

Look, I know everyone wants stuff for yesterday or the past life, but tag wiki/excerpts are the kind of thing that for accuracy, you may foregone any other perk (Documentation should be like this, too). These posts have the potential to be very useful for multitudes, but it's just a mess without control. If having these edit wait more for better reviewers, god is blessing those edits. They would be reviewed by a reviewer and not a mindless clicking machine.

Comment: I think the point being made was that any given *edit* sits in the *queue* for longer and longer, not that it takes time to actually *do* the review.

Comment: @Draco18s and what exactly I'm saying? They take longer to be reviewed.

Comment: "It takes more than 12 seconds to approve/reject" and "It takes eight days for them to be approved/rejected" aren't necessarily correlated.  Does A have an impact on B? Sure. But is it the *only* cause? Is it the biggest cause?

Comment: @Draco18s I'm not sure what you are getting at but here's another: **If I have to wait weeks for a reviewer to review a tag wiki suggestion like God says™, I will gladly wait it**.

Comment: @Braiam i think the point is that a lot of the people who are reviewing the edits are only doing the easy ones thus meaning the review queue is getting bigger so it then takes longer to get through them

Comment: @WhatsThePoint how can you do "the easy ones" when the queue spews suggested edits at random?

Comment: @Braiam: Using that "Skip" button

Comment: Edits that "**should take longer**" prevent question edits and answer edits from being suggested at all because the queue is full. Why is this desirable?

Comment: @DamianYerrick Do you know that the hard limit is arbitrary? Why do you think there should be a limit?