# Incorrect information on Help Center 'Edit Questions and Answers' page

Tags: bug, help-center

The '[Edit Questions and Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit)' page has not been updated to reflect the fact that suggested edits on Stack Overflow now only require two votes instead of three (at least per [this Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349118/is-the-top-bar-redesign-the-sole-cause-of-the-suggested-edit-slowdown)). It still states that three votes are needed to approve or reject an edit.

Comment: Yes, looks like the part *",except on Stack Overflow where three votes are required"* can be removed, since there is no difference to other Stack Exchange sites anymore.

Comment: Just thought about making the same post you made here, still isn't resolved apperently....

Comment: I was just about to ask the same question when I found this, it looks like it's been for a long time now. Any updates about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The 'Edit Questions and Answers' page has not been updated to reflect the fact that suggested edits on Stack Overflow now only require two votes instead of three

Seems it has been updated.

If so, a [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) would be appreciated.

Comment: Not a moderator so I can't add it.