# Help Center: Privileges - edit questions shows outdated info

Tags: bug, edits, help-center

Since the redesign of the top bar reduced the amount of reviews taking place the requirement for suggested edits to be accepted or rejected were changed on SO, making them inline with the rest of the SE network. However the helpcentre still states that three accepts or rejects are required:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit

> Reviewing suggested edits
>
> In addition, users with this privilege level can also begin reviewing suggested edits (which previously you would have had to suggest). These edits remain in a pending state until they get enough votes to either approve them and make the edits take effect or reject them and discard the edit. Two votes in either direction will finalize the action, **except on Stack Overflow where three votes are required.**

There are some other questions about this as well:

[We are down to two, so the help center should say the same](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351918/we-are-down-to-two-so-the-help-center-should-say-the-same) (marked status completed) I raised a custom flag on this, but that got rejected suggesting me to make a new post

[Incorrect information on Help Center 'Edit Questions and Answers' page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349613/incorrect-information-on-help-center-edit-questions-and-answers-page) Which gained a fair amount of upvotes.

However for two months now it hasn't been resolved.

Comment: Yes it is a dupe, but two months in still no fix has been implemented....

Comment: And?  Changes take 6 to 8 weeks...

Comment: 8 weeks <  2 months

Comment: The timeline is kind of a joke: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/291223