# Reputation documentation still refers to Documentation as a source of points

Tags: bug, documentation

The help page [What is reputation?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) says this:

> - first time an answer that cites documentation you contributed to is upvoted: +5

I believe this should be removed because the documentation feature is gone from the site.

**EDIT** [Martin Smith](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/73226/martin-smith) noticed that this is obsolete as well:

> - example you contributed to is voted up: +5

Comment: It's planned. It will be effective around 6 to 8. Months.

Comment: @TGrif *citation needed*

Comment: There are way more things in the HELP center that needs updating. All in 6 to 8 weeks I was told... For example: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354705/help-center-privileges-edit-questions-shows-outdated-info

Comment: There are still lots of lingering mentions of Documentation. The [teams](https://stackoverflow.com/teams) page is one for example.

Comment: Should we make the Help pages editable, in the same way as the Q&A posts?