# Do I get notified if the edit suggestion I approved got edited again before it is accepted?

Tags: support, review-queues, suggested-edits, notifications

I suggested an edit to a question and I understand that it needs 3 positive reviews to be accepted.

What I did is, I improved my edit further more and it got accepted.

What I wonder is if the first user who approved my suggestion got notified with my second edit before it got accepted or not?

What is bothering me is, what if the second edit was bad and the user would not approve it if he saw it again.

Comment: **"needs 3 positive reviews"** - 2 ... **"if the first user who approved my suggestion got notified with my second edit"** - No.

Comment: There is still a mention of 3 in the helpcenter....

Comment: @Tom As mentioned by Luuklag, the help center marks as 3. But sometimes my edits get approved by 2, or even 1(not sure if I had those).

Comment: @SteveFest Then the help center is obviously wrong (actually outdated, it was 3, but thas changed to 2).

Comment: @Tom You are correct. My first suggested edit actually got 3 "approves" before going live. Maybe they should have update their help page.

Comment: @SteveFest They definitly should. You can search this meta site if one already asked about an update of the help center page and if you can't find one, then feel free to create one. (But it should be fixed already: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351918/we-are-down-to-two-so-the-help-center-should-say-the-same ... or your question is more related to this (still open) meta post: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349613/incorrect-information-on-help-center-edit-questions-and-answers-page)

Comment: @Tom I quickly took a review on the edit help page, and I couldn't find any clue on '3' or '2' "approves"...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, reviewers do not get notifications.

So the scenario is indeed possible. If a reviewer saw the modified edit, and would normally Reject it... they're not notified. Also they can't review it again, either. The Approval stands.
(And obviously it works the other way around too - if they've Rejected first and would Approve the new version... they can't.)

Fortunately, this is not a real problem in practice. Most of these "follow-up" edits are in line with the original edit.

When in doubt about an edit you want to make, feel free to ask. Either on Meta or in an appropriate chatroom.

In general, my advice is to err on the side of caution. Only edit the things you are certain about. That way, you stay closest to the OP's intention.

Comment: This is one of those cases where we employ Pallet-Of-Bricks protocol - if someone abuses this hole for malicious intent, we're probably going to come down on them like a pallet of bricks. As you say, I'm not aware of any incident of someone abusing this.