# Why does Stack Overflow allow editing/removing the tags after the question was closed by a gold tag badge holder?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bug, dupehammer

Why does Stack Overflow allow editing/removing a tag from a question, after the question was closed by a gold tag badge holder for that tag?

Go to this question:

[Can't bind to 'ngOutletContext' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-template'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47221088/cant-bind-to-ngoutletcontext-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-ng-template)

The question is not tagged with the [javascript] tag. But it's showing a message: "**marked** as duplicate by **Günter Zöchbauer** [tag: javascript] 4 mins ago*"

[image: Screenshot of dupe hammer closure banner]

You can see the revision [status here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47221088/revisions). He closed the question by using the JavaScript gold tag badge. But after he closed the question, he  removed the JavaScript tag. **Is this okay? Or a bug?**

Comment: The dupe target doesn't seem to have a JavaScript tag either...  nor has it [ever had one](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/40418598/revisions). Strange.

Comment: Weird that the tag that they removed was the same that they used to gold-close... Would the removal of a tag send the post back to the re-open queue?

Comment: Actually this question does not related with `javascript`. ` Günter Zöchbauer` would be closed by an `angular` gold tag instead of `JavaScript` tag. But my question is difference. did you understand my question? **Why SO allow to to remove a tags after closed by the same tag as a golden badge tag.** It's not a good logic and user's might not understand what is happened.

Comment: @yivi it would.. any edits to question pushes it

Comment: @SurajRao in that case, closing and _then_ editing does seem a bit impractical.

Comment: @yivi ideally OP should be editing the question to suggest if it is not a dupe. Its one of the cracks in the system.. Not a bug in the site IMHO..

Comment: @RameshRajendran [tag:improvement-request] is for the now shutdown documentation improvements..not features

Comment: @SurajRao Sorry, I didn't mean it was a SO bug. Only that it isn't very practical to close a question and edit it immediately afterwards. You are closing the question and sending it to the reopen queue, despite believing the question should remain closed.

Comment: @yivi maybe SO should give a warning message if anyone other than OP edits a closed post.. just a thought.. Other than that users with edit privileges should exercise caution.

Comment: @SurajRao also same as don't allow to remove a tag which is closed by a golden badge tag ';( .

Comment: @yivi And why you guys are speaking with unrelated topic of this question? if you have a doubt then make a new question.

Comment: Why is it a problem when the tag gets removed? In addition, the user who closed it has a gold badge also for angular which stayed in the question. I don't think you can choose which tag shows up in the close message.

Comment: @RameshRajendran is the issue here removal of _the_ tag after it is closed with the dupe hammer of the same tag or is it about a user removing a tag after closing the question?

Comment: it is  about a user removing a tag after closing the question @SurajRao

Comment: @S.L.Barth: There have never been any tag requirements for dupe targets.

Answer (score 10):

Closing and retagging are separate issues. So far, there hasn't been a reason to explicitly forbid a gold badge holder from re-tagging a question they closed.
In fact, adding this logic would make it less desirable for gold badge holders to use their dupehammer. After closing, they would no longer be able to re-tag - but they are the ones most likely to know if a tag is applicable.

As an example, suppose there is a question about a Null Pointer Exception. These are the same in C# and in Java. So a Java gold badge holder closes a C# question to the canonical Java duplicate for "What is a Null Pointer Exception". Now the gold badge holder notices that it was a C# question, not a Java question - should they be forbidden from removing the Java tag?

It *is* actually a loophole, however, and maybe there is a way to abuse this loophole. But if some creative user finds a way to abuse this little loopole, we can apply the [pallet-of-bricks protocol](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356073/do-i-get-notified-if-the-edit-suggestion-i-approved-got-edited-again-before-it-i/356132#comment511151_356132):

> if someone abuses this hole for malicious intent, we're probably going to come down on them like a pallet of bricks.

Until then, it's not happening often enough to be worth restricting gold badge holders.

Comment: Similarly, Angular *is* a Javascript framework and even with zero Angular experience you can probably tell when an issue is directly related with the Angular environment and not to JavaScript as a whole... and vice versa!

Comment: Just for the records: C# has its own [canonical dupe target](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4660142/3959259) for NullReferenceExceptions.