# What should happen if an edit suggestion gets edited again by the editor before the review completes?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

> **Note:** Some of this issue is covered by [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/356073/8376184), but I want to discuss this from a different viewpoint.

The main question is: **What should happen if the person who suggested an edit, edits the same post again (maybe differently) after it has got review votes, but the review haven't got completed yet?**

This question was inspired by a scenario that has just happened to me:

I've [suggested an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/5017679) to the [ecmascript-2020](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-2020) [tag wiki excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ecmascript-2020/info).

> ECMAScript 2020 (ES2020) is the 11th version of the ECMAScript language. It adds many important new features, including dynamic imports, globalThis, optional chaining, arbitrary precision BigInts and Promise.allSettled.

Later, I noticed that the review has got a *Reject* vote, because it didn't explain how the tag should be used.

As I agree with that vote, I've quickly fixed it by editing it again, adding the following sentence:

> Only use this tag where the question specifically relates to new features or technical changes provided in ECMAScript 2020.

However, I noticed that this suggestion didn't get a new review entry, but just updates the original.

> **Note:** This question isn't about me personally, or about that my edit has got a Reject vote. This info is just for context.

> **Note:** My question doesn't only apply to tag wiki edits, but to regular edits too.

---

I think that this can lead to several problems:

- Incorrectly rejected or approved edits

  There's a greater chance for that edit to be handled in the way as the first vote (as only 1 more of that completes the review, while it takes 2 against-votes to complete it in the different way)
- Responsibility issues

  In a such case, the second reviewer can single-handedly complete the review by agreeing the first vote. Therefore, they will be the only one responsible for reviewing (or, possibly, mis-reviewing) the edit, but nothing (except the timestamps) indicates that.
- Moderation issues

  The user who cast the first vote [isn't notified about the change](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/356073/8376184), and cannot retract or change their vote.

**What should happen in this case?**

In my opinion, in this case,  the original review entry should be put into a sort-of "disputed" state (like flags), and a new review entry should be put into the review queue. What do you think about that?

Comment: "and a new review entry should be put into the review queue." So if the first reviewer rejects my edit I could just make some change and thereby resubmit it endlessly until it's approved?

Comment: @JeanneDark That's a good point. Then, what do you suggest?

Comment: @JeanneDark Other than being banned from suggesting edits, that's basically what happens now when an edit is fully rejected. There isn't anything, other than the complete ban from suggesting edits, which prevents someone from just re-suggesting an edit which had been rejected, even if it's exactly the same change.

Comment: Orthogonally to this, I once requested a timed lock on editing posts when a user started an edit. It was shot down due to the technical difficulty. I imagine this also would be sufficiently technically difficult for the amount of benefit it would produce.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Suggested edits have a long grace period that permits additional changes. As a matter of fact, the grace period only ends once the review is complete.

There are no records kept of edits made to a suggested edit—not even moderators can see this information.

I was going to say *this doesn't happen often*, and I assume that is true, but without hard data I leave it at that. Still, I don't think it is much of a problem. A review gets completed once it receives two approve or two reject votes (and few other [corner cases](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/190581/158100)). If we assume good faith on the part of both reviewers and suggester, then in the end we will have with better content—and that is what matters.

Creating a new review task doesn't seem necessary. In the slim chance that the two reject votes are reached even after you made an edit, you could wonder if the edit was really all that awesome. There is no penalty for reviewers when they chose *reject* and the edit is approved later on. And a rejected edit can be re-submitted later if the analysis is that the first revision contributed to the rejection.

Nothing needs to change for now.

Answer (score 9):

Ultimately, I think that so few people change their suggestions after a review vote that the system is ok how it is. It can be abused but so can a lot of things: there are flags, and  moderators with the ability to manually suspend people to handle situations like this. And any edits that are rejected despite being improved would not be a problem for good editors, who wouldn’t be on the verge of not being able to suggest a new edit like normal.

If we did see a larger problem emerging here it would make sense for an approve vote to block further changes, which would prevent anyone from vandalizing a theoretically good edit.