# Reviewing while edit queue full?

Tags: discussion, support, review-queues, edits

With the new changes to the suggested edit queue, I have been running into a small conundrum while going through the First Post and Late Answer queues.

I have now on multiple occasions come across very well written questions and answers that I would like to pass on with 'No Action Needed' except there are some small formatting changes needed to the code. It's nothing that damages the usefulness of the post but usually indenting and other small corrections to code that help overall readability. But when I try to edit the post, I find the review queue is full and I cannot submit an edit. This leaves me to choose either hit 'No Action Needed' and hope that someone fixes the formatting later, or just skip the review and hope it can be fixed when it comes back up for someone else.

I normally just choose 'No Action Needed' since I think the question should go through, but is this correct? Should I just let these smaller edits go by?

Comment: There were no changes to the suggested edit queue recently, it's simply getting less traffic than it used to.  The queue size has been there for many years.

Comment: @Servy That's good to know. I'm not sure where I got the idea the limit was new then.

Comment: You may just hit skip and hope someone with enough privilige will show up to save the world. A responsible user will certainly fix those minor formatting problems if he saw it in the review queue.

Comment: It would be nice if the bypass the queue limit check for theses cases.

Comment: Just for reference there seems to be a problem with the edit queue since the top bar was changed https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349118/is-the-top-bar-redesign-the-sole-cause-of-the-suggested-edit-slowdown

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Part of the purpose of the queue is to find and fix formatting problems, minor wording and clarity issues, etc.  Yes, the queues are partly there to find spam and egregiously bad content, but it's also there to help out with acceptable content that just needs some small improvements.

Saying that the post *doesn't* need any improvements when it really does is wrong.

Comment: I'm also pretty sure it doesn't clear out the queue any faster: edits still need to be reviewed by 2 people.

Comment: @Draco18s 1 user less from what it used to, and if we were honest, that's still too much.

Comment: This leads to an obvious next question: does anyone know if anything is being done to fix the congested suggested edit review queue?

Comment: So maybe add another choice: "Needs editing at some later time when the queue allows" ;-)