# "Edit queue is full" alert not working while reviewing?

Tags: support, bug, review-queues, suggested-edits, first-post-review

I was reviewing some first posts right now and I felt there was some edit needed.
Just some indentations, grammatical corrections and replacing links with images. I might leave some corrections as mentioned [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350377/reviewing-while-edit-queue-full). But the actual issue is mentioned below.

When I click the `edit` button, it doesn't show me any error like (*review queue full*). But when I do the necessary changes and click `save edits` it shows me "Edit Queue is Full" error. The edit was not so serious just a line of code was outside the code block. But sometimes the edits need much correction.
I thought the queue may have got full while I was editing so I tried again and the `edit` button worked and allowed me to edit. Though the `save edit` button still persisted on edit queue full.

Why am I not getting an alert saying "Edit queue full" while starting the edit like we get when editing a post directly. Is it a bug? I get this issue only in review queues. This sort of wastes time on editing there is no safe as draft or such option.The alert saves some time which can be used to review other posts. I might just skip the current one then.

Comment: It might be that the queue wasn't full when you started editing but either way that is a pretty lousy experience.

Comment: I thought this was a duplicate but.... couldn't find one, only found ones about why the button didn't work if there was a pending edit. That said, I'm more concerned about the fact the edit review queue has been on and off full for the last week at least

Comment: @rene no. I've mentioned that in the question. The edit button works, but the `save edits` buttons gives the error. So I tried again and the `edit` button opened the editor again but I wasn't able to save edits due to the fact that edit queues were full.

Comment: @Nick no there's no similar issue. I had checked it twice with different phrasing.

Comment: It's strange that the edit queue is now full all of the time. I wonder if we are doing less reviews or if more suggestions are submitted?

Comment: @BDL not sure. I just suggested 4 edits today. 5th one got me in the above issue.and yes none of them got accepted or rejected yet.

Comment: @Nick Exactly, me too.

Comment: Just got bitten by this on a post with a fair bit of rework. In my opinion, SO should allow in-process edits to be submitted even when the queue is full.

Comment: It is incredibly frustrating to spend time editing a post and then getting this error trying to save it. Is there any development to improve this experience?