# We are down to two, so the help center should say the same

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, help-center

> Two **(three on Stack Overflow)** accept or reject votes are required to remove the suggested edit from the queue and either apply the edit to the post or discard it. Users with more than 2,000 reputation are considered trusted community members and can edit posts without going through the review process

Since [Shog reduced the amount of reviewers required](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/349125/792066) to deal with a suggested edit, this bit isn't true anymore. Can someone fix this?

Comment: candidate for fastest [meta-tag:status-completed] ever

Comment: @psubsee2003 I bet Shog was like "darn, forgot that thing..."

Comment: Related: [Incorrect information on Help Center 'Edit Questions and Answers' page](/q/349613/) ?

Comment: @Shog9 This is still going on, so marking this status-completed is not really appropriate. https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit

Comment: @Shog9 "Two votes in either direction will finalize the action, except on Stack Overflow where three votes are required." in Luuklag link. The last paragraph