# Review-banned users should be able to see what posts they reviewed incorrectly

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, review-suspension

### Background story

Recently I got my first review ban which lasts for 7 days (I presume since I noticed it today when there are 3 days left) for reviewing a tag edit incorrectly. I agree with that I should've payed more attention to [**the review in question**](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15395868), but since the ban seems to have been for **7 days** I can only presume that I reviewed something else incorrectly as well since, in my opinion, 7 days seems rather harsh for that little review (and from what I understand the minimum ban is 2 days).

The message:

> You reviewed https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15395868 incorrectly. This edit copied a significant amount of content from an external source. Please pay more attention to each review in future

### The problem

The ban seems to have been done by a moderator (hence why it doesn't explicitly say that I've made **too many** incorrect reviews), but not being able to see the other failed reviews makes it very difficult for me to understand what I could've possibly done wrong.

### The suggestion/feature request

I suggest that the user would be shown a list of his/hers recently failed reviews (for which he/she has not been "published" yet) along with the ban reason.

This would help users *that actually want to improve* to understand what they should think about and/or do better.

Comment: This was a punitive action by the moderator, no prior failed audits were necessary to get the ban.  More about it [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318288/stopping-tag-wiki-plagiarism-part-ii-taking-action).  Well, I gave it a shot.

Comment: Since this question is asked almost daily for some time it may be good idea if moderators put a custom "pay special attention for tag-wiki edits"...

Comment: The quote that says "most reviewers won't be able to see the post got banned for" is outdated, as the feature-request linked in the original has already been implemented. Any reviewer always has the opportunity to see all of their past reviews, and all the deleted posts they reviewed, by going to their history for that queue.

Comment: @NathanTuggy : Yes you can see your _history_, but AFAIK you cannot see which ones _you reviewed incorrectly_ (if I'm wrong please correct me). The purpose of seeing which you reviewed incorrectly is so that you can be aware of what you did wrong and improve.

Comment: Oh, I think you're assuming something that doesn't exist. There's a way to [see what other reviewers did](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251508), and there are manually-identified reviews that were wrong, but the system has no concept of marking all possible wrong reviews. What you see in the message is what there is.

Comment: Related from 2013: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199218/moderators-should-have-easy-access-to-a-users-complete-review-history-includin which links to a similar request at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169159/is-it-possible-to-see-own-review-queue-audits-results

Comment: @NathanTuggy : I know I can see what others did. However the system keeps track of how many audits you have failed, so surely there must at least be the _possibility_ to implement keeping track of which you failed at (not every last one of course, but the ones that have been identified so far). I know it doesn't exist, which is why this is a feature request. :)

Comment: FWIW the [guidelines for reviewing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155538/168333) are on Meta Stack Exchange.

Comment: @VisualVincent: But you didn't fail an audit (or at least that's not why you were banned), so it wouldn't help you here. If you just want to see audits, the script already linked will help with that.

Comment: @NathanTuggy : I know I didn't fail an audit, but that doesn't stop me from wanting to see where I've gone wrong before and what I can improve. Without at least seeing a list of the posts for which I got banned, I can not know if the ban was caused only by a single post or by multiple (prior to Hans's comment I was not aware of this). I would still like to see the the feature however.