# "Copied content" rejection message is malformed

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, markdown

The message on rejecting a suggested edit on a tag wiki or tag wiki excerpt appears to be malformed:

> This edit copies a significant amount of content from an external source. Generic descriptions such as encyclopedia articles and ad copy do not provide useful guidance; try creating something [useful to this community specifically](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/03/24/redesigned-tags-page/), and be sure to attribute the original author. See: [How to reference material written by others](https://stackoverflow.com/ / help/referencing).

It's rendered as in the following images in the wild:
[image: on completion]
[image: while reviewing]

Once, this was probably [working](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358580/3157076).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A typo snuck into the markdown last week. I pushed a fix and it'll be live with the next prod build.

Comment: @francescalus Nah, it was apparently 6 days ago and I misread the commit history. It's all good. Thanks for the report!

Comment: If it goes unnoticed for a week you need to give kittens/hat/badges to people who reject copied content ;).

Comment: @francescalus Or an angry badger for not reporting this sooner. ;)

Comment: New build live and that's one shiny link to the page.