# What are these strange suggested edits?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

I'm getting suggested edits in the review queue like these:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19792418
https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19787913

where empty posts by the Community user are being edited into whole new paragraphs. Among the tags it says "tag wiki", but the content doesn't look like a tag wiki at all. At first I thought they were audits, but I'm not getting the familiar "that was a test and you've passed/failed" reply.

I rejected the first one, but I probably shouldn't have, since I'm not sure what these are.

Comment: the first one is now rejected, that is clearly a question typed in some textbox on the internet. The second one is serious work but for a tag wiki it seems to be missing how/when to tag questions with  that tag, links to canonical question et.

Comment: I can imagine to improve edit that pymodbus wiki but it is not my area of expertise so don't look at me ...

Comment: @rene - It turns out it was all copied from here anyway and edit rejected.https://github.com/riptideio/pymodbus/blob/master/README.rst

Comment: @MartinSmith ah, I should have checked that ... me and my assume good faith ...

Comment: If it mentions only one tag and then "tag wiki" or "tag excerpt" then it's an edit to the tag wiki/excerpt. Such reviews are shown to those with >5k rep. In addition to the normal requirements for a tag wiki/excerpt, you are specifically charged with checking for plagiarism: [Stopping tag wiki plagiarism, Part II: Taking Action](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318288)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Regarding the first edit, if there is a text box on the site, someone will type a question into it. This unfortunately includes tag wikis, from time to time. Reject those as quickly as you can, and if you see someone doing it more than once, give us a custom moderator flag about it.

The second edit was plagiarized from the product page, so I took the liberty of rejecting it as such. When I see formatting and descriptive text that looks like it was lifted from a Readme in a tag wiki, it often is.

Comment: So they are simply edits to tag wiki's. Oddly enough I've never seen one of these in the review queue, and now there seem to be a lot at once. Maybe there's a coordinated "improve the tag wiki's" effort going on today.

Comment: @m69 Tag wiki edits require 5k rep to review, rather than the 2k rep for regular suggested edits, so you weren't able to see them for quite a while.

Comment: Is there a name for this textbox rule? If not, I propose we call it the Larson Law or Larson Rule.

Comment: @TylerH - Perhaps the Shog9 Conjecture, based on where I first heard it years ago.

Comment: @BradLarson how about Plan Shog9 from Stack Overflow?

Comment: For what it's worth, plagiarized tag wiki suggestions are pretty common. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20490969) one I rejected not too long ago. They usually sound "off" for a tag wiki - too glowing, too generic.