# I do not understand the current tag description of [persian-calendar]

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

The current tag description and excerpt of [persian-calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/persian-calendar), [approved 3.5 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10343031), reads:

> Concered with **Calenders** and **Datetimepickers** in Jalali calender and also converting other calenders to Jalali Calender.

I don't understand it, so I can't improve it:

- What is *Concered*?
- Why is it spelled *calender* four times, when the tag is named *calendar*?
- How does it relate to [jalali-calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jalali-calendar)?
- *Datetimepickers* isn't in the dictionary: if it's a control specific to a given framework (Twitter Bootstrap?, Microsoft .NET?), does it mean that the tag shall only be used for such frameworks?

Could someone come up with a clearer usage guidance and description?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't really understand your confusion. "Concered" is clearly a typo for "concerned"; "calender" is an obvious typo for "calendar", the number of times it appears notwithstanding.

A tag wiki excerpt that has typos in it and does not contain helpful usage information is not exactly a "stop the presses" moment. I'll bet dollars to donuts this isn't the only one with egregious errors.

I've gone ahead and rejected [that edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10343031), because it's useless and should never have been approved. Tag wikis are a huge mess. Almost half of them are [plagiarized](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318288/stopping-tag-wiki-plagiarism-part-ii-taking-action), and the other almost half are useless. Yet, they get approved because reviewers don't know what they're looking for and don't like to hit the "Reject" button. In either case, you're welcome to raise a moderator flag and request that these revisions be reverted.

It is, however, rather clear what this tag excerpt was *trying* to say: the tag is meant for questions about the Persian calendar, which is (according to the creator of this tag description) the Jalali calendar. The tag can be used both for questions about the use of the calendar itself in UI controls (such as DateTimePicker controls) as well as for questions about conversion between the Jalali calendar and other calendar systems.

Now, I'm not anywhere close to an expert in this, so I don't know if what the creator of the tag description was assuming is true. Calendars, time zones, and geopolitics are extremely complicated. Persia isn't even a place anymore, I can't say for sure whether modern-day Iran uses the Jalali calendar or the Solar Hijri calendar, nor do I know what the difference is between these two calendars. I don't know if the description is merely historical (medieval Persia did, in fact, use the Jalali calendar), or whether it is accurate today. Unfortunately, Meta isn't really a good place to find experts or request tag wiki edits. Maybe you'll get lucky.

Comment: "_Meta isn't really a good place to find experts or request tag wiki edits._" ... oh? I thought Meta was to seek help too.

Comment: I would revert the wiki excerpt too in that case.

Comment: Sigh, there's another one? I thought that *was* the excerpt. Okay, rejected now as well. Yeah, you *can* ask on Meta, but you need the perfect storm of a Meta user who also happens to be an expert on Persian calendars. Not terribly likely. Opening a Meta question for every tag wiki that needs to be edited doesn't exactly scale. Tag cleanup requests are already enough of a problem for Meta to handle. We desperately need better tooling around tag wikis, but I dare not wish.

Comment: Some "wizard text" (in HTML comments) could be the first step. It could include "Do not copy-paste directly from Wikipedia and other sources. Instead XXX".

Comment: Agreed; we definitely need more XXX in tag wikis.