# Why was I asked to Review an edit by a user with higher rep than I have?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, tag-wiki

I was recently presented with [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24599093) in the Suggested Edits queue. I'm not here asking about what the 'right answer' is/was (the edit was a simple 'correction' from a "\" to a "/") - more curious (at least, to me) was that when I scrolled down, I saw that the user who proposed the edit had (at the time) **6,817 reputation** - certainly more than the 5,000 required for wiki edits and, as it happens, more than I have (5,238 at the time).

Maybe not that important, but it piqued my curiosity sufficiently to post this question!

*PS: I clicked the "Skip" button in this case due to inherent uncertainty about the validity of the correction.*

Comment: So that you can [check the suggested wiki for plagiarism](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318288/stopping-tag-wiki-plagiarism-part-ii-taking-action), and reject it if it is plagiarized. Obviously not relevant in this case, but for new wikis that are being suggested, grab a few random sentences and copy-paste them into Google. If there are any hits, reject.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need [20,000 rep](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) to edit tag wikis without review/approval by other users.

Comment: OK - thanks for the clarification! I assumed the "approve tag wiki..." at 5,000 implied one could edit without approval.