# Questioning plagiarism from outer source review audit

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, plagiarism

Recently, I failed [an audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers/31639218) that was plagiarised from an [external source](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/different-ways-to-fix-default-activity-not-found-issue-in-android-studio/). I agree that this is pure plagiarism and should not be accepted.
As I was reviewing, I noticed the high view count and 'fishiness' of the answer, coming to the conclusion that this is an excellent answer audit that should be accepted. Turns out it was actually an audit of an answer with plagiarism from an external site?

I am simply wondering how much we are supposed to search for plagiarism in the First Answers review queue.

Comment: Has the comment been visible during the review?

Comment: @BDL Nope, it was hidden.

Comment: *"we will verify if our Activity name is declared in our Manifest file or not"* (from the answer) ... "our" twice with a link to an external site ... and you already noticed a certain "fishiness", but still selected "looks ok"?

Comment: @Tom, Yes, I've seen plenty of answers work through the problem as if they were doing it with the asker, and linking to other sites to back up their answer is also not uncommon. The strangeness of the question so convinced me that this was a good post that I didn't even check to make sure. Part of the problem is that I've never even considered checking the whole internet for plagiarism for each review. (But maybe I'm missing your point.)

Comment: If I have any qualms about a review, I cheat and load the actual question page to get more context. If the question or answer has been deleted, it is definitely not OK and usually there are some breadcrumbs explaining why. Not a satisfactory answer for you, but I agree. How are you supposed to know a post was plagiarized unless you know the poster's writing style (and this ain't it) or have previously encountered the source from which the post was taken? Maybe paste a snippet into Google and see what comes up?

Comment: Related (different queue): [How much effort looking for plagiarism is expected of a reviewer of a tag wiki edit?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/414925/215552)

Comment: The system probably shouldn't be using moderator deletions like that...we delete for a variety of subtle, non-obvious reasons.  As for the immediate suspension, I've lifted your review suspension.  The others listed in the suspension notice were more legitimate, but you've also previously received a review suspension for them, so re-suspending you here was a bit harsh.

Comment: In general, you probably *should* be keeping an eye out for plagiarism to some degree, though.  And this one *does* look a little...off.  But it's not expected to the degree that it is in tag wikis, where it's so common that we have a built-in reject reason for it.

Comment: "I am simply wondering how much we are supposed to search for plagiarism ..." - Use one of the major search providers.  If a contribution is too well written from a new user, then my spider senses which are actually plagiarism senses go wild, and I typically am able to find the original source of the well-written text.  In this case, I read a single sentence, and Immediately knew it was plagiarized.  "In this method, we will verify if our Activity name is declared in our Manifest file or not." **reads as a professional writer wrote it.**; The phrase "this method" is the dead give away

Comment: @RyanM, Ok, thank you so much. That clarifies things. I feel the problem was that I wasn't even considering plagiarism from an outer source for an audit, and was caught off my guard. After this, I will definitely try to be more 'aware' of the legitimacy of the answer.

Comment: @SecurityHound, Right, but how would I know that it was a new user's plagiarism instead of a professional user's genuine post? In the audit, details are hidden, (and I should have checked the original post), but that aside, how was I supposed to know this was an audit to be rejected? I also realise that I am simply not as experienced at spotting this sort of thing.

Comment: What is the canonical regarding plagiarism? The best I could find is *[Answers entirely copied though properly attributed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/)*. For example, *"simply tacking a "Reference" link at the bottom of a wall of unquoted text, as is the habit of an alarming number of users, does not count as proper attribution"*

Comment: Re *"how would I know that it was a new user's plagiarism instead of a professional user's [writer's] genuine post?"*: That is a good question. ***Statistically*** it is the case (99% or more are not professional writers). In the particular case, the user name is a lead. [The profile text](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10563627/paresh-mangukiya) uses weird capitalisations of nouns (most likely because a very old version of English is in use. Less likely for emphasis (formatting options *are* available (a subset of raw HTML is accepted))). This does not fit with the post.

Comment: @PatrickYoder - How do I make that determination, experience, most user’s questions are the written form of verbal diarrhea. They write their questions like this our community is Yahoo Answers