# Are reviewers expected to research for internet-wide plagiarism in the First Answers review queue?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, plagiarism, specific-audit

I just failed [the following audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers/31879665) and was thus suspended from reviewing.

A comment from a mod taught me that the seemingly innocent answer was copied without attribution from [this off-SO origin](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5242/adding-users-to-azure-sql-databases/).

I don't think there could have been any way for me to know this, or even to suspect this is the case. Are reviewers expected to research for internet-wide plagiarism in posts, similar to [Wiki edits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/414925/how-much-effort-looking-for-plagiarism-is-expected-of-a-reviewer-of-a-tag-wiki-e)?

---

Some of the comments about spotting **plagiarism of on-site answers** are very informative and useful, but I'd like to clarify that the compexity here comes from the fact that this is **off-site plagiarism**. You can't tell that by checking out other answers.

Sure, reviewers can google every OK-looking answer to see if it's plagiarised (or open every review in a new tab to see if it's an audit), but is that considered something reviewers are expected to do?

Comment: Spotting plagiarism is so important for curators; learning how to spot it is something you learn. I, personally, have a mistrust of low reputation users who post content like what you saw in your review; especially so when the content is written like it *had* formatting and blocks of text that appear to be missing (in this case, the code wasn't copied from the source, making the answer quite disjointed).

Comment: You could notice the tone, google the content and see what you find.

Comment: Presumably the comment pointing out the plagiarism was not visible when you saw the answer?

Comment: @khelwood Yup, and I believe comments are never visible on First Answers audits, but I'm not 100% sure on that. It makes sense though because that would enable reviewers to interact with comments on deleted posts, see that they can't and figure out it's an audit

Comment: it'd be easier to just install an extension that makes audits obvious

Comment: Related: [Questioning plagiarism from outer source review audit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417734/15497888)

Comment: When reviewing I always check the original question  if I have any hint of bad feels about the post or just got paranoid because it had been a while between audits. That happened often enough that I pretty much stopped reviewing. Too time consuming.

Comment: "Are reviewers expected to research for internet-wide plagiarism in the First Answers review queue?" - When something is that obviously plagiarized, I would say the answer to your question is, absolutely. Learning to identify plagiarised content as others have said is important. Suspension from a single failed audit is unlikely, so that means, you have failed more than a couple of audits recently.  Here is the reason it's so obvious, the answer is **clearly** missing text, specifically the queries that were suggest from the original source.