# Can we have some care when reviewing wikis edits? How can we improve our wiki edits?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits, review-audits, tag-wiki

There's been a fair bit of attention to tag wiki plagiarism

[Let's stop tag wiki plagiarism](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313486/lets-stop-tag-wiki-plagiarism)

[Stopping tag wiki plagiarism, Part II: Taking Action](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318288/stopping-tag-wiki-plagiarism-part-ii-taking-action)

This post is about improving the quality of our wikis via edits and the part reviewers take in this.

This is more a post to gain awareness and discussion about it,  it's more of a brain storm than a question.

[This  wiki edit has two approvals](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15075240). The two users who approved the edit have no tag badges in [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift) or [objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/objective-c).

Now I don't either, so I researched it.

[Wikipedia - weak references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_reference)

A SO Q&A [Why passing a weak reference to a block prevents an object from being retained?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27848089/why-passing-a-weak-reference-to-a-block-prevents-an-object-from-being-retained)

and taken from [the swift docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html):

> Because a weak reference does not keep a strong hold on the instance it refers to, it is possible for that instance to be deallocated while the weak reference is still referring to it. Therefore, ARC automatically sets a weak reference to nil when the instance that it refers to is deallocated.

Plus [discussion taken from here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/35462622#35462622).

Can people please research topics you are not aware of or skip reviewing edit suggestions on wiki tags? Or [perhaps get some advice](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/35462622#35462622)?

Apart from making meta posts, what can we do to educate people not to make uneducated reviews of wiki edit suggestions? Review audits?

Comment: Pinging both reviewers to make them aware of this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42012701/add-variable-value-to-button-in-jquery/42012735#comment71207649_42012735 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637666/chrome-extension-modifying-user-agent/40282322#comment71207645_40282322

Comment: Just a comment about my routine. When I come across a tag wiki, I *always* put at least some part of it through Google verify that it has not been plagiarized. Maybe if we put in some safeguard to prevent this or use some kind of userscript to do this automatically...?

Comment: @AndrewLi yep the same. I'm afk. I know people can be funny about people posting and leaving their keyboards :D

Comment: I have no expertise in Swift or Objective-C, but it seems to me that the edit is simply removing information that is not required in the tag wiki. The information may well be correct, but does it belong in the wiki?

Comment: @Blackwood The edit comment says *"why is this not approved yet? the current text on the site >>>is wrong<<<"*, which seems to indicate that the editor is removing it because he believes it's wrong.

Comment: @Pang Possibly, but assuming the information is correct (as I said, this in not my area), does it need to be in the wiki? It seems to be describing details of the concept that apply to some but not all of the applicable languages.

Comment: That paragraph [is *technically* incorrect in Swift](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2015-12-11-swift-weak-references.html), since it says weak references will be **immediately** deallocated when there are no strong references, but that's just an implementation detail and is irrelevant  to programmers.  Whether or not that's what the editor was referring, he certainly should have been clearer in his edit summary, and he shouldn't have deleted the whole paragraph.

Comment: Well, at least this edit looks like it could make sense - while this edit clearly does not and also got two accepts: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15064184

Comment: Just so you know, Tag wiki edits [are not returned](http://stackapps.com/a/3173/42239) by [the SE API](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/suggested-edits). After scratching all the parts of my head, I came up with a [workaround and wrote an app](https://github.com/SOBotics/TagWiki-Monitor) to detect tag wiki edits. You can use it to monitor wikis. (I try to catch the plagiarists whenever I'm online).

Comment: We really just need to make tag filters the *default* setting. Filter the review queues to show only things with tags the reviewer has earned a token amount of reputation in. The argument against this is it doesn't scale to smaller tags. Well, fine. Let 10k+ users review everything, but filter lower-rep users by default. Maybe even allow them to remove the filter if they want. I suspect most won't. If you're smart enough to understand and remove the filter, you are probably a good reviewer. As for plagiarism, I still support adding automatic detection on the software side.

Comment: @cody, I've banned a few 10k+ users also. But, true, that would reduce a lot of bad reviews. The plagiarism part is also quite easy to implement, IMO. The Bing API is free for 5000 requests and there are around 30 tag wiki edits everyday (not telling that SE is broke not to afford the paid version). Heck, if they just add tag wikis to the API, we can find those copy cats and robo reviewers easily.

Comment: @BhargavRao  What if someone has permission to use certain content on a tag wiki? The Bing API doesn't know that, right? Let's say that I write something about jQuery somewhere and I copy that text to the tag wiki, is that plagiarism?

Comment: @g00glen00b Oh, that has happened. We once banned a user who plagiarized a lot. Turned out that they were the creators of the web page from where they copied it. But yeah, even if they are the owners of the content or have permission, SO has a   [referencing](http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) policy. If they stick to it, then it should not be an issue.

Comment: @BhargavRao the title says "How to reference material *written by others*", so is it applicable if you copy your own content?

Comment: Ah, Good catch, @g00glen00b, Not sure about that. I'll find out about that and let you know.

Comment: @piet.t that's a good catch. That's a terrible edit

Comment: @YvetteColomb thankfully it eventually got rejected...

Comment: @BhargavRao Seems it would be easier if tag wiki edits were kept in a separate review queue than other suggested edits. Possibly with a requirement that the editor/reviewer needs to have some badge in the edited tag, if it is an existing one with lots of activity.

Comment: @Lundin I agree http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277031/can-we-have-tag-wiki-and-wiki-excerpt-edit-reviews-in-a-separate-queue-to-sugges

Comment: @YvetteColomb A shame that the post haven't gotten more attention. Up-voted.

Comment: @Lundin totally agree. I would put a bounty on it, but most of the bounties I've used have not helped, except when I posted a bounty of 400

Answer (score 9):

A review tip is to always grab the first 2-3 sentences of the text and paste it in Google. If it is plagiarism, you will almost always spot it that way.

You can also save time by only looking for plagiarism when the edit is otherwise ok. Before you do any plagiarism research, see if there is any tag usage description etc. If not, then that alone may be reason to reject the edit.

Comment: Yep, For excerpts, it's best if you could first check the tag usage. This would help in tuning the reviewers mind to reject a bad tag excerpt edit, even if it wasn't plagiarized. Usually everyone makes that mistake. There's one proposed even as we speak about it http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15093404

Comment: Yes I currently subscribe to this for reviewing tag wikis

Comment: Why doesn't the review page do that search for us?