# Why did I fail this audit? (yet another title)

Tags: support, review-queues, review-audits, specific-answer

https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/22549650

I don't understand. The answer maybe incorrect and I didn't check it. Because when I recently flagged one incorrect answer as "very low quality" it was declined. So, the question is about regex and the answer is about regex, it provides code that can solve the issue, so it maybe valid. I really don't understand what should I do with this audit... I must check every answer to be correct and if not, downvote it? I think nobody has possibility to check every answer.

Comment: The answer appears to be a code-only answer, one without textual explanation of the source of the OP's problem or why they are proposing this code solution, and this then would be classified as a low-quality answer.

Comment: There were many discussions about code-only answers and my opinion is that they can be valid. What should I do in this situation? Do not review? Or always skip them?

Comment: If you're unsure, always best to skip

Comment: I've updated my answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

<strike>Personally I find these types of answers difficult to moderate. We're told to encourage explanations, yet they fall under the category of being an answer.</strike>

I missed the fact it was a ***late answer review***.

When dealing with a late answer you need to look at the other answers. There's an expectation it's bringing something to the table on top of the existing answers. This answer doesn't, so recommending deletion is the correct action.

The purpose of review bans is to make reviewers think and reflect upon their actions. Given it's one of those borderline cases I unbanned you from review.

Also, if in doubt, [skip](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356451/reminding-people-to-pay-attention-and-use-skip-when-reviewing).

Comment: Even if the moderator finds them difficult to moderate, I will skip the next times I see code-only answer. Thanks for unban also.

Comment: @Sanyash I totally understand and I skip reviews sometimes even now.

Comment: this is not a border case, but rather simple late answer review, with thorough guidance provided in many prior meta posts. Skip would of course work here but besides it, discussed audit could be easily passed with vote down or comment

Comment: This is the late answers queue, not the LQP queue. Answers without explanation are almost *always* not-so-good and thus improvable (which a reviewer should prompt via voting down, commenting, or editing), even if not necessarily "LQ" and subject to removal. Agree with @gnat, this doesn't look borderline.

Comment: @gnat oh yeh, you're completely right a late answer review. I'll have to update this later.

Comment: @CertainPerformance yep you're right. I totally overlooked it was a late answer review queue.

Comment: So.. is OP having any kind of incentive to pay attention more or were they simply unbanned and will continue as they were?

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier I unbanned the OP as I thought it was a different queue. Either way they should have learnt something and will skip if in doubt. If they fail again they will have another auto ban for longer.

Comment: @Felix Don't you think this Meta discussion is sufficient?