# Plagiarised tag info of [webdeploy]

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-wiki, plagiarism

The [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/webdeploy/info) of [webdeploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webdeploy) is plagiarised. It is a plain copy from the website that is linked to ["check more details"](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy)

Comment: Unfortunately [only one reviewer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1418863) noticed it's plagiarised.

Comment: It's rolled back now - thanks. If someone wants to (suggest an) edit the tag wiki - feel free.