# OK to fix Excel VBA tags programmatically instead of manually?

Tags: discussion, tags

**Is there *any* reason** that existing questions that are tagged **[excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba)** **should not** be updated to **also include tags [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel) and [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba)** (if not already included)?   
 
 
Users have made this edit manually to thousands of questions over the years.

I'd like to do so programmatically.<sup>***†***</sup>

---

<sup>***†***</sup><sub>Note: This Q is **not** asking whether tags(s) should be burninated to prevent this issue. That is a separate [debate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=vba%20excel).</sub>

---

```
  Excel or VBA tags used (with or without others)                  
 ---------------------------------------- -------- 
  [vba]+[excel]+[excel-vba]                 40541  
  [vba]+[excel]                             19325  
  [vba]+[excel-vba]                         12255  
  [excel]+[excel-vba]                       12293  
  [excel-vba]                               13649  
  [vba]                                     28768  
  [excel]                                   75521  

  Questions with any an Excel or VBA Tag   218907
```

Comment: How would this work if a question already has 5 tags?

Comment: It'd be more cool if some tags came with "implied" tags. :) But that'd be a major change in how the system works.

Comment: @AndréKool Hypothetically: How many questions would that encompass, especially given it is VBA. And could those, if small enough in number, be put in a review queue for review of appropriateness of tags? #Playing devil's advocate.

Comment: How would this programmatically close questions that need closing, or edit other things about the posts that might need editing?

Comment: Well, @QHarr there are 78K questions with the excel-vba tag... On the first page of most recently active ones, I found [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51016408/is-it-possible-to-convert-xlsm-macro-files-to-json-in-php) that has four tags currently and lacks both vba and excel... and another two on the second page. So if there are 1577 pages and there's one per page, that's 1577 to fix. Heck, on the third page it's clear this is already a concern as there are two that ashleedawg has edited to have five tags that are missing either excel or vba.

Comment: @QHarr [And they keep on coming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51029553/vba-for-loop-where-each-answer-must-true) (Posted 2 min ago with 4 tags)

Comment: :Sobs openly and retreats:

Comment: I think [this MSE FR](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223400/can-we-group-constrain-and-add-heirarchy-to-tags/258678#258678) might help for situations like this but, as I said in my first comment, getting it added would require a pretty major push from the dev side, I think... and figuring out who gets to establish the implied tag hierarchy could take some discussion. Something similar to synonyms but without preventing the usage of the individual tags.

Comment: @AndréKool - Indeed - in some cases (15%) the questions wouldn't be automatically updated because there isn't enough room, but that still leaves almost 50,000 questions that *can* be updated to add missing tags.

Comment: @ashleedawg Actually that [isn't a problem for Shog](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370095/merging-the-excel-vba-into-vba-speak-now-or-forever-hold-your-peace#comment603465_370095)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The bigger issue here is: do we even need an [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba) tag?

If we *don't*, [I can add](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356057/duplicates-dichotomy-excel-vba-vs-excel-vba#comment512845_356080) [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel) to every question in that tag, and merge it into [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba), thus doing what you suggest for all 25K+ questions in the span of a few minutes; that'd save you probably about a day running a script to do it.

...but... That only works if there's absolutely no use for a stand-alone [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba) tag. If all questions currently using this tag are about both Excel and VBA. And even then, it potentially throws a wrench into the workflow for folks who currently follow [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba) but don't care to follow either [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel) or [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba), so we'd want to make sure that they're ok with such a change.

If we can't answer those questions, then running a script isn't a good idea either. So let's answer 'em: [Merging the excel-vba into vba - speak now, or forever hold your peace](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370095/merging-the-excel-vba-into-vba-speak-now-or-forever-hold-your-peace)

Quite honestly, I hate these hyphenated tags. Occasionally they're a necessary evil, but in this case I just don't see it and would be happy to be rid of it entirely.

#### Related:

- [Duplicates dichotomy: [excel-vba] vs [excel] + [vba]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356057/duplicates-dichotomy-excel-vba-vs-excel-vba)
- [Tag editor extraordinaire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288749/tag-editor-extraordinaire)
- [User on tag-edit spree for 2+ days... [excel]+[vba]=[excel-vba]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364745/user-on-tag-edit-spree-for-2-days-excelvba-excel-vba) (that one looks familiar, eh?)
- [Synonymize / rename [excel-vba] and others to [excel-automation] / [excel-activex] / [excel-objects] / [excel-object-model]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300056/synonymize-rename-excel-vba-and-others-to-excel-automation-excel-active)
- [Merry Go Round Situation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305546/merry-go-round-situation)

Comment: I've been playing around with adding the tags programmatically, but would sure appreciate if you could do it instead...  Every question that has [tag:excel]+[tag:vba] should also have [tag:excel-vba] added. Any with [tag:excel]+[tag:excel-vba] should have [vba] added. Any with [tag:vba]+[tag:excel-vba] should have [tag:excel] added. Any with [tag:excel-vba] should also have both [tag:excel] and [tag:vba].  I added questions counts for each tag combination above.

Comment: Hooray!  Thanks dude.  I'm looking into manually going through some of the ones are are going to be more difficult (ie., >5 tags) where some human decision would be needed.