# User on tag-edit spree for 2+ days... [excel]+[vba]=[excel-vba]

Tags: discussion, tags, edits, suggested-edits, burninate-system

I'll save you looking it up: [Here's the duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314488/how-to-deal-with-serial-tag-only-edits-from-sub-2k-users) of my question.  I figured I should pass this along anyway since I couldn't find a clear answer on this.

I've noticed someone who is <2k rep and for at least the last two days has had practically **no activity besides dozens of pointless tag-only edits**.

Here's a couple of examples:

- seeking posts tagged [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel) + [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) and [editing to add] [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba)
- seeking posts tagged [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) + [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba) and [editing to add] [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel)
- seeking posts tagged [ms-word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-word) + [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) and [editing to add][word-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word-vba)
  *etc*

About 40 of these in 2 days (and picking up speed?), and none of these edits have any other changes.  There are a few non-tag-related (yet pointless) edits like this one for capitalization.

I realize he can only ever do 500 of these for 1000 rep, and it's not hurting "much" except for clogging up the queue unnecessarily (and annoying one person at least!)   I think I'm counting right; if I understand correctly a *suggestion* turns into a *revised*, so each edit shows twice in activity?  (If I'm wrong, it's double what I thought.)

<sub>[profile links removed after discussion with user]</sub>

---

On a side note, the tag combination was already on my mind because, in my opinion, **we should get rid of [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba) since it duplicates [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel) and [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba)**.

...(regardless of how they *occasional* could have separate meanings) because this duplication will always cause confusion (and the above) unless every user is aware of the existence and usage of all related tags.

Comment: It is a chronic problem with [vba].  Prior discussions: [one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356057/duplicates-dichotomy-excel-vba-vs-excel-vba), [two](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295302/is-this-implication-true-excel-vba-excel-vba).

Comment: Letting the user know can be useful, done.

Comment: @Hans - i responded on at least one reject.  There have been other rejects too.

Comment: I feel like I have to answer here; the main idea was originally "if some user got excel-vba on his feed, he maybe want receive the vba or excel tag too". Although I thought there is a reason the three different tags exist, since they belong together? But: Will not happen no more, so sorry for that. Also, it would be enough to contact me (instead open a Q on meta).

Comment: @Essigwurst: Your edits are not particularly bad. If you do these edits are on new questions and are done after getting the edit privilege, I guess noone would have complained.

Comment: @Essigwurst - oh it's you, interesting, I'm curious how you found this post.  Obviously it's nothing personal (seeing as I don't know you) but was enough of a frustration for me that I felt it necessary to seek direction here. I didn't think you had any ill-intent (there's not that much to gain @ 2 rep/edit)... and mahbe it's an OCD/Coding thing (I get that!) but, if 3 tags exists, that implies that they do **not** automatically need to be together every time, or else there would be 1 tag...

Comment: @BDL - I never said they were *bad*, I say *unnecessary*.  All of those questions, in my opinion, apply to VBA + Excel + Excel VBA, which is **exactly* my argument as to why the tag shouldn't exist.  If new users aren't aware of the need to include all 3, or if searchers aren't aware that some questions might not include"only Excel-VBA", then someone ends up losing out.  Being a big geek for both VBA *and* for Excel, it stands to reason that, as much as I like the idea of Excel-VBA taking 50% of the tagging/searching effort, and as many will argue, there is *indeed* a few....

Comment: ... semantic cases where Excel+VBA≠Excel-VBA, the fact is that, unless near-100% of users were aware of not only the difference, but even the *existence* of the 3 tags, they are doomned to continue the debate which isn't going to end anytime soon. I could calculate tangible figure to show the amount of time that could be saved (in discussion, review queues, searching, etc) by simply **removing** the Excel-VBA tag and retagging existing posts with both Excel & VBA...  but I am also aware that the probability of my whining about it actually *changing* anything is somewhere between Null and Zero.

Comment: @Essigwurst - you didn't do anything "wrong" (and if there was a way to get a hold of you directly, I would have opted for that), but you did draw attention to a battle that's been going on here since long before either of us joined this site.  I despise arguments that continue with no resolution... It's not like we're talking about creationism versus religion here.  :-)   ***@Everyone*** - if I created a short/simple Google Forms Survey on the topic, "to burn or not to burn tag X/Y/Z", would that be frowned upon in this democratic online society? Maybe put an end to the topic once & for all?

Comment: @ashleedawg It's about my user, so it concerns me.. (also, I can see some links to my profile). But, when I think about it, you'll go probably right when the `excel-vba` tag would be removed... Although, as I said, I thought it will be useful to some people. Btw, there's a contact at my profile ;)

Comment: @Essigwurst - I've removed references to your profile.  And yes, you do have contact information there, that's unusual around here... (and Salzburg eh?  I've been there; half my family is in Munich and area... small world,)

Comment: "if there was a way to get a hold of you directly" - there was. Find an approved edit in a question, and comment underneath using that editor's handle. The name auto-complete does not kick in, but the notification system works just fine.

Comment: @halfer  you call that direct?!   I mean like "summon someone to chat, or send a PM etc"  or even an email relay service.  I know SO wants to prevent all that though.  but an "off-topic comment" on an unrelated post isn't direct either (and breaks a different rule)

Comment: @ashleedawg: ah, I see - did you mean off-site?

Comment: @ashleedawg: I agree that this discussion ought to have been had off-Meta to start with, but if you cannot find contact details for a user in their profile, then ping them in the manner I have described, and ask how you can best contact them (e.g. if you would rather keep it private). It's not terrible that you brought it here, but I tend to suggest a constructive chat first - it can resolve some criticisms without a Meta discussion being necessary.

Comment: @ashleedawg: regarding the new point in your comment edit: sure, comments on the main site are not for extended chat. You can request contact details there, and then delete the comments when you've received that info.

Comment: I don't use it very often, but I believe you can start a chat with any user as well (as long as they have sufficient rep for a chat). Search for their profile in the Chat site, [e.g. like so](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/6348874/essigwurst) and then create a new room from there.

Comment: A slightly different perspective on this issue, I once came across a user that was adding [java] to [jpa]-tagged questions. While JPS is a Java-based framework, in that instance the user was not only flooding the edit queue with trivial tag edits, they were polluting the [java] queue with questions that were specialized for a specific framework rather than more generic java-based questions. A custom mod flag ended up with that user's edits being reverted and what I presume was an edit ban (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) I don't believe this case is as severe, and seems to have already been resolved amicably judging by the above comments, but minor tag edits have a cost on this site as they flood the already-busy edit queue. Each 2k+ user only gets 20 edit reviews per day, so if they're wading through a flood of minor tag edits it'll take longer to reach more substantial or helpful edits that may be in the queue.

Comment: Related meta question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303373/what-to-do-when-i-find-a-user-suggesting-a-large-number-of-trivial-edits/303381#303381