# Do we need a [coreldraw-vba] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

A while ago I posted 2 questions about using VBA with CorelDraw. Both were tagged with [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) and [coreldraw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coreldraw), which seems quite self explanatory.

A few minutes ago a user edited both of them to add a new tag [coreldraw-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coreldraw-vba):

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8251417
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8251425

(both edits were (robo?) accepted within 1/2 hour)

It looks to me as if [this tag may have been created by that user in order to tag my two (pretty unique/useless) questions](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8251838).

Do we really need this new tag? With 2 questions, 1 unanswered?

Looking for moderator input on this. Do we pre-empt the need for a tag cleanup by nipping this one in the bud?

---

Related posts:

- [Is it improper to use the vba tag on application specific vba questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252933/is-it-improper-to-use-the-vba-tag-on-application-specific-vba-questions)
- [Is this implication true: [excel] + [vba] => [excel-vba]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295302/is-this-implication-true-excel-vba-excel-vba)

---

### Update

It seems we didn't need this new tag. Questions were untagged quickly and the tag itself has been removed.

Comment: We need a moderator to stop this guy.  If one doesn't respond to this post then flag one of the edited posts and use a custom flag.

Comment: @Hans, I mod flagged _two days_ ago, left him a comment on one of his posts two days ago, poked a mod a short while ago, and still nothing has happened.

Comment: @Richard, No, you'd have to comment on one of his posts or where he has made an edit.

Comment: @HansPassant, I think it is more like "we should reject trivial / questionable edits".

Comment: @Jonas I absolutely agree, but I'm trying to find out about the tag first. That trivial/minor etc thing has been hashed over so much I'm quite happy to remove that edit. But then I won't be the ["top asker"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coreldraw-vba) on any amazingly useful new tags any longer.

Comment: I pinged the user in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26384517/coreldraw-print-merge-automation-with-vba) (you can ping editors of a post the same way as other commenters).

Comment: Another problem is that both coreldraw-vba and coreldraw-C# use (pretty much?) the same object model: expertise on one will generate expertise on the other.

Answer (score 12):

This user's [reputation source is 95% edits](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4897144/shruti1810?tab=reputation). There are several days when they got a 200 rep gain just for edits.

Most of them are just minor fixes, adding or removing tags (usually something-vba). See these:

- This is an epic edit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8251394.
- `[excel]` + `[vba]` = `[excel-vba]` https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8251618
- `[while-loop]` for off-topic question, being on hold: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8251710

On the good side, edits are sometimes reasonable. On the bad side, they are way too small. And sometimes they are useless, such as `[corel-vba]` or editing a tag on unsalvageable question. They only take the reviewers time.

Overall statistics is:

> shruti1810 had 455 edit suggestions approved, and 57 edit suggestions rejected

In my opinion, this user does not understand the SO policy about edits (and about answers too, probably). Thus, their ability to edit should be limited or revoked for some time.

Possibly best solution would be to help them understand what is a good edit on SO. Their [2000 rep milestone](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) is coming soon with the ability for unmoderated edits.

Comment: I'm not sure how to interpret your last paragraph, but even at 2k, mass editing tags onto questions is bad, at least without getting community consensus (on Meta) first. Kind of ironic that he reaches the 2k editing milestone from bad edits..

Comment: @JonasCz I think Nick's saying that the problem could become when that milestone is reached.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm yes, that is exactly my point.