# New tag being created for a single java class

Tags: discussion, tags

Going through the suggested edit review queue there were a couple question that were edited by a user with a tag edit to add [simplefilevisitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/simplefilevisitor).  I know there are tags out there like [map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/map) and [vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vector) but those are general language agnostic tags where this is just about Java.  Should we be creating a new tag just for a single Java class?

Comment: Was this done by the same user in this question? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295565/do-we-need-a-coreldraw-vba-tag What is going on?

Comment: @BSMP No.  It was done by the creator of the first question in the tag.

Comment: At least for [the question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22907653) which I saw, it's worthwhile to note that the tag is even irrelevant to the question because it's not about `SimpleFileVisitor`, it's about calculating a progress bar value with an indeterminate total. *"Tags should help to describe what the question is about, not just what it contains."*

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I would say "No, nuke the tag."

Along with the [coreldraw-vba] tag [BMSP linked back to](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295565/do-we-need-a-coreldraw-vba-tag). Otherwise, what other simple classes can get their own tags?

Maybe we can create a tag for `System` or `NotificationManager`. Before we know it we will have tagged the whole API.

Comment: I went ahead and rolled back all the edits.

Comment: Yes, tags for individual classes, methods or properties are 99% of the time not useful for categorizing (there are a few exceptions).  What tends to work better for tags are whole APIs or concepts.

Comment: @Manu he's determined he added them back!

Answer (score -12):

> Should we be creating a new tag just for a single Java class?

There's already many out there, especially for the Swing classes (`JFrame` or `JTable` for example).

So, if the use of a particular class tends to invoke a lot of questions, then why not?

Comment: Does the downvoter care to add to the discussion?

Comment: That's a rhetorical question that only forces me to say "wusn't me". I'd say if you found such tags, they should be reviewed for burning rather than opening the floodgates. They're Java Swing questions.

Comment: "Does the downvoter care to add to the discussion" generally down-vote on meta should be treated as "I don't agree with/like this opinion" and there is no obligation to explain it, just like with up-vote (you don't need to explain why you agree with some opinion).

Comment: @Pshemo - fair enough.

Comment: +1, "*if the use of this particular class tends to invoke a lot of questions*" is just the correct policy on tag creation. And while I had been quick with a "no" because I've never heard of this class, it does in fact seem to have provoked [a few dozen questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=simplefilevisitor+is%3Aquestion).