# Synonymize / rename [excel-vba] and others to [excel-automation] / [excel-activex] / [excel-objects] / [excel-object-model]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, synonym-request

The Microsoft object models for the various Office applications are language-agnostic; they can (generally<sup>1</sup>) be used equally well from any OLE-Automation-supporting language. Use of the API is the same between all these languages; there is nothing specifically VBA about the object models. Moreover, in most<sup>5</sup> cases, it is the same DLL/EXE referenced from the different Automation-supporting languages.

For the most part, questions tagged [*-vba] are questions about the object model in question; such questions -- and their answers -- could have been asked and answered under any Automation-supporting language, or with any host environment (Word, Excel, CorelDraw, Classic ASP, WSH). <sup>2</sup>

- There are some questions tagged [ * -vba] which relate to VBA syntax or pure VBA objects (collections, arrays, classes), and do not relate to any specific object model. Tagging with [excel-vba] or [word-vba] on these questions only because the host application is Excel or Word seems unjustified; they should just be tagged [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba).

Therefore, I propose synonymizing the [ * -vba] tags to something language agnostic and that more accurately conveys their meaning -- [ * -objects] or [ * -object-model]<sup>3</sup>; or perhaps [ * -automation], or even [ * -activex-automation]<sup>4</sup>.

Since these questions are about the object model in any case, there is no loss of information in automatically retagging the question and setting these aliases.

(The relevant tag wikis would have to be changed appropriately, but that is a follow-up to this discussion.)

---

**There are other libraries for working with Office documents. Shouldn't they also be tagged with [ * -objects]?**
Libraries/APIs such as [xlwt](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt) and [Office Open XML SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx) are focused on extracting data from Office documents. In contrast, the Microsoft APIs are designed to automate the application (although they can be used to extract data as well).
In addition, the Automation APIs are provided by Microsoft, the publisher of these applications, and can be considered the official object models.

**Why [ * -objects] + [vba] and not [ * ] + [vba]?**
It could be argued that there are subdomains to Office applications programming, such as [excel-formulas], [excel-addins], [word-fieldexpressions], that should be differentiated from automating Office applications with the supplied API.

**How will new users know to use these tags?**
The same way users until now are guided to tag with both [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) and [ * -vba] -- via the tag wikis for [vba].

**What about people who don't know what an object is? [They won't understand this tag!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/300059/111794)**
What is the purpose of a tag? To attract the attention of experts who follow this tag and might be able to answer the question. It's rather unlikely that an expert in programming the object model will not know what is an object. (Perhaps not the formal "object == state + behavior", but at least in the sense of a programmable entity.)
Regarding askers who approach a programming QA site (this already presumes some knowledge) with a question on how to automate Excel for example, either they understand what an object is (at least as a thing that can be manipulated in a program), or they cannot.
* If they can, the tag makes perfect sense.
* If not, they will inevitably get an answer which they don't understand (they have no idea what is an object), so there is nothing wrong with guiding such users to use a tag incomprehensible to them. Alternatively, they could be guided to use the [excel] tag.

---

1. I have come across the following edge cases.
   (a) Javascript depends on the host to provide mechanisms for [connecting event sources to event handlers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974564.aspx).
   (b) I've had trouble passing arguments to properties in CPython + pywin32.
2. Questions on programs written in VBA and under a specifc host application should still be tagged with VBA because of the language, but they shouldn't be used to justify all the [*-vba] tags.
3. Technically more accurate, but perhaps less approachable to newcomers to programming.
4. To distinguish the Automation object model — the Microsoft object model for automating these applications under OLE Automation — from other libraries such as [xlwings](https://www.xlwings.org/).
5. I know of one exception - .NET Office Interop.

Comment: I spent most of this wondering what `FooApp` was; some sort of VBA environment? Maybe clarify near the top that `FooApp` means one of Word, Excel, etc. for dummies like me.

Comment: @ZevSpitz I think you can escape the \* with a backslash. Or does that not work in tags?

Comment: @rene There is [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278718/combination-tags) discussion, but the question here is specifically about [tag:foo-vba]; that question is more general.

Comment: None of those discussions come close to my proposal here. e.g. _Is [tag:vba] + [tag:excel-vba] + [tag:excel] superfluous?_, _Are edits in that direction worth doing, hamrful, or harmless?_. Noone seems to mention that when questioners tag [tag:excel-vba] they actually mean [tag:excel-object-model], and that [tag:excel-vba] should thus be replaced with [tag:excel-object-model].

Comment: Relevant: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252933/3198973

Comment: i would love to see [tag:excel-vba] become [tag:excel] + [tag:vba], but we can't even burn [tag:macros].....

Comment: To be pedantic, when you mentioned COM, you actually meant "OLE Automation" (because while you can consume OLE Automation object models from pure COM, doing so looks a lot different and requires a lot more information -- interface names and DISPIDs -- the sort of stuff that type libraries provide)

Comment: @ZevSpitz I'm not arguing with you. I'm just stating the fact that you'll need community support and help that you're just not going to get.

Comment: Too much work? Too many awful questions flooding in each and every day to keep up, let alone get ahead of it? Idk. I'm just saying it's unlikely that anyone wants to manually retag tens of thousands of questions.

Comment: No. That won't work. You can't just synonmize it.

Comment: Because you'll inevitable muck it up and lose information in the process. The right thing to do is tag [foo-vba] with [foo]+[vba] and you can't do that with a synonym.

Comment: RE: _summary of comment discussion with @RubberDuck_ -- I was (and am still) trying to understand why this is a bad idea. **RubberDuck** A manual retag is too much work. **Me** clarification - not manual retag, but a tag rename+synonym closer to actual meaning. **RubberDuck** Information loss on retag [foo-vba] => [foo]+[vb]. **Me** No information loss; [foo-vba] is actually used for [foo-objects].

Comment: @Zev: Thanks for the heads up, but I think I'll leave that comment since it contains relevant information which many viewing this discussion may not have known.

Answer (score 18):

> In that case, the tag should certainly be vba, without reference to
>   the specific host in which the VBA is being run.

I completely disagree with this assertion. As @rene pointed out, [see this answer.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295385/656243)

Putting all of that aside, let's take a moment and consider what the purpose of a tag is. It's there to allow categorization of questions. It caters to a specific audience, too. Who do you think the majority of the [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba) users are? Who comprises that audience? My bet is: business types, not programmers. Execs. Accountants. MBAs. Not programmers.

Now, let's consider your proposal: [x-object-model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/x-object-model) Hrmm. Hold on; I'm going to walk down to my marketing VP and ask if the term "object-model" means anything.

> It does not magically become a different language when used within FooApp.

True, syntactically, it is the same thing as vb6. But think about the terribly rich object model that's only to be found in Excel. You won't find Worksheet anywhere else. It's a completely different beast than .. say .. classic asp users are familiar with.

Comment: RE: your response to my assertion - If someone is writing VBA in Excel and forgets an `End Function`, should that be tagged as [tag:excel-vba]? Should it be tagged [tag:excel] at all?

Comment: RE: rich object model - The rich Excel object model is only a **Tools -> References...** away from any VBA environment you might choose to use it in. The only difference (besides the global objects I mentioned in my post) is that in Excel you don't have to manually add the reference; it is done for you.

Comment: @ZevSpitz, Python has a set of excel tags other than simply `excel`. They aren't used nearly as frequently, but they do exist and are used when the author understands what modules they are using

Comment: @ZevSpitz Three off the top of my head: [xlrd](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd), [xlwt](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt), [xlsxwriter](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/XlsxWriter)

Comment: RE: your other answer -- The proposed question in your other answer needs both the Access and Excel object models. That it is taking place in a VBA environment is secondary.

Comment: @Andy I've now addressed this in my question.

Comment: @rene Like it or not, the community has decided that there should be an [excel-vba] tag to differentiate between [excel-formulas] and [excel-addins]. I'm only suggesting that this tag not be called "something-vba", but more descriptively and accurately.

Comment: _the point of a tag is to allow categorization of questions_ -- Exactly. Questions in Python, C#, VBScript and Classic ASP about how to manipulate the Excel object model should be caregorized together with the VBA questions; this would provide far more value than an arbitrary language-specific categorization. These tags prevent that sort of categorization.

Comment: @ZevSpitz Please don't edit content out of answers that don't belong to you. It isn't nice.

Comment: Your position is opinion-based, but either way - you are correct that edits should not be made _even when the content is wrong_. Your options for content that you would like the OP of the answer to modify are: (1) comment and (2) downvote.

Comment: @ZevSpitz If you want to make yourself heard, please post an answer to this question. Otherwise, I would ask that you leave Lynn Crumbling alone, both by avoiding making edits to their answer and by avoiding attempts to engage in a protracted debate via the comments section. Simple disagreement can be expressed by a downvote.