# Where to post research data consisting of links to questions?

Tags: discussion

I think [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300056/renamesynonymize-very-bad-amalgam-tags-excel-vba-access-vba-word-vba) would benefit from some informal research. I want to examine the last 30 questions from a fixed date in each of those tags to verify empirically that they could have been asked under any VBA host environment, and include the results in my question.

A list of 150 links to questions is probably not the best way to do so. I would certainly post a summary of what I have learned (X host-independent questions, Y VBA syntax questions, Z host-specific questions); but I would also like to include a reference to the links of the questions I am using.

What is the best way to include this information in the question?

Is it possible/advisable to use SQLFiddle and/or JSFiddle for this purpose?

Comment: If it's relevant to an existing meta question, I'd include a link to a SEDE query that returns those results. Otherwise, probably a blog post.